# "Sum equals integral" identities similar to $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^x} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

It is quite a well known fact that:
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
also the value of related series is very similiar:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin n}{n} = \frac{\pi - 1}{2}$$
Combining these two identities and using ${\rm sinc}$ function we get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {\rm sinc}\, x \, dx = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} {\rm sinc}\, n = \pi$$
What is more interesting is the fact that the equality:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {\rm sinc}^k\, x \, dx = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} {\rm sinc}^k\, n$$
holds for $k = 1,2,\ldots, 6$. There are some other nice identities with ${\rm sinc}$ where sum equals integral but moving on to other functions we have e.g.:
$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{+\infty} \binom{\alpha}{n} e^{int} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \binom{\alpha}{x} e^{itx} \, dx = (1+e^{it})^\alpha, \; \alpha  >-1$$which is due to Pollard & Shisha.

And finally the identity which is related to the famous *Sophomore's Dream*:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^x} = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^n}$$
Unfortunately in this case the summation range is not even close to the interval of integration.

Do you know any other interesting identities which show that "sum = integral"?

Comment: In http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13543/are-there-other-analytic-functions-with-this-property-of-sinc-function/13566#13566 I showed an approximation to a function that the sum (1 to $\infty$), the sum of its square, the integral ($-\infty$ to $\infty$), and the integral of its square all agree

Comment: @RossMillikan If summation of a series would range also from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ than ${\rm sinc}$ is a nice example.

Comment: I think one should be able (though it's not obvious to me how except for trivial cases) to generate a wide range such identities by finding functions that kill off the sum and remainder terms in the Euler Maclaurin integration formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: @Sam:  I think any four functions that are properly summable and integrable can make one by taking a proper linear combination.  You just sum an integrate the combination and have four equations in four unknowns.  I just used the ones I did because the sums and integrals were tractable.

Comment: One can imagine that Poisson summation is a formula of this sort, although the reality is more complicated (the sum of Fourier transforms resist being expressed as a single integral). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula

Comment: Actually I would be more interested in neat examples rather than general methods for finding such functions.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Factorial and exponential dual identities](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/20441/2370).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Several papers are dedicated to the subject of integrals of functions that equal the sum of the same function, primarily for estimation purposes.

[Boas and Pollard](http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Papers/Published-InPress/Sinc-sums/Related/boas.pdf) (1973) has some interesting sum-integral equalities:

$$\pi/\alpha=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 (c+n)\alpha}{(c+n)^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 (c+n)\alpha}{(c+n)^2}\, \text{d}n$$

$$\pi\operatorname{sgn} a=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (n+c)\alpha}{n+c}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (n+c)\alpha}{n+c}\, \text{d}n$$

It also gives several general formulae for functions that suffice:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(n) \, \text{d}n$$

mainly with Fourier analysis.

---

[This](http://rsc.anu.edu.au/%7Epgill/papers/159_Bessel.pdf) paper gives an equality with the [Bessel J function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind_:_J.CE.B1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{J_y (at) J_y(bt)}{t}\, \text{d}t=\sum_{t=-\infty}^\infty \frac{J_y (at) J_y(bt)}{t}$$

and some more references:

> There have been a number of studies of this kind of sum-integral
> equality by various groups, for example, Krishnan & Bhatia in the
> 1940s (Bhatia & Krishnan 1948; Krishnan 1948a,b; Simon 2002) and Boas,
> Pollard & Shisha in the 1970s (Boas & Stutz 1971; Pollard & Shisha
> 1972; Boas & Pollard 1973).

---

See also [Surprising Sinc Sums and Integrals](http://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Ejborwein/sinc-sums.pdf) which has some other equalities.  This paper also states that (paraphrasing)

*If $G$ is of bounded variation on $[−\delta, \delta]$, vanishes outside $(−α, α)$, is Lebesgue integrable over $(−α, α)$ with $0 < α < 2\pi$ and has a Fourier transform of $g$, then*

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty g(n)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\, \text{d}x+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(G(0-)+G(0+))$$

---

Ramanujan's [second lost notebook](http://www.scribd.com/doc/48940173/Ramanujan-Notebooks-II-pdf) contains some sums of functions that equal the integral of their functions (Chapter 14, entries 5(i), 5(ii), 16(i), 16(ii)).

---

If you want, even more references with examples are in the papers I have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. These references are very helpful.

Comment: Excellent answer! But would you be so kind as to update the links to the references most of which are broken? Thank you.