# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\text{Si}^2(\pi n)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was doing numerical calculations and found

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{\text{Si}(\pi  n)}{\pi n}\right)^2\overset{?}{=}\frac{1}{2},$$

where $\text{Si}(x)$ means the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral). Interestingly, it seems that only when the terms are squared can the result be a rational number.

I attempted to evaluate the following series expansion about $x=0$:

$$\frac{\text{Si}(\pi  x)}{\pi  x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(\pi x)^{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^2 (2 n)!}=1-\frac{\pi ^2 n^2}{9}+\frac{13 \pi ^4 n^4}{2025}-\frac{8 \pi ^6 n^6}{33075}+O\left(n^8\right).$$

But it didn't give me any clue. I still have no idea about how to evaluate

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ \displaystyle\left(\frac{\text{Si}(\pi  n)}{\pi n}\right)^2.$$

Comment: This is a nice one, for sure ! Did you notice how slow is the convergence ?

Comment: It can be solved using Fourier series, Parseval identity and the sampling theorem for the Fourier transform (sampling $\frac{Si(\pi x)}{x}$ is the same as periodizing its Fourier transform)

Comment: Please no `\displaystyle` in titles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{Si}(\pi n)}{\pi n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(\pi n x)}{\pi n x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
hence for any $z\in(0,1)$
$$ f(z)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\text{Si}(\pi n)}{\pi n}\,\cos(\pi n z)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{W_z(x)}{x}\,dx \tag{2}$$
where $W_z(x)$ is a piecewise-linear function over $(0,1)$, with a jump discontinuity at $z$, $W_z(0^+)=W_z(1^-)=0$ and derivative equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$ at any point of $(0,1)$ which differs from $z$,
 by [the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave). It follows that
$$ f(z) = \int_{0}^{z}-\frac{dx}{2}+\int_{z}^{1}\frac{1-x}{2x}\,dx=-\frac{1+\log z}{2}\tag{3}$$
and by Parseval's theorem
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{\text{Si}(\pi n)}{\pi n}\right)^2 = 2\int_{0}^{1}f(z)^2\,dz=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(1+\log z)^2\,dz\stackrel{\color{green}{\checkmark}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\tag{4}$$
as conjectured.

Answer (score 4):

I combined both of my answers into one answer.

---

If $-\pi \le a \le \pi$, and if we define the value of $\left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(az)}{z} \right)^{2}$ at $z=0$ to to be its limiting value, then we can use the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) under the weakened conditions mentioned in [achille hui's answer to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1596564) to get that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(an)}{n} \right)^{2} = a^{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(an)}{n} \right)^{2} =\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(ax)}{x} \right)^{2} \, dx + \frac{a^{2}}{2} +i(0),$$

where, integrating by parts, we get $$ \begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(ax)}{x} \right)^{2} \, dx  &= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (ax)}{x^{2}} \operatorname{Si}(ax) \, dx \\ &= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^{2}} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(axt)}{t} \, dt \, dx \\ &=2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax) \sin(atx)}{x^{2}} \, dx \, dt \tag{1} \\ &= \pi \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\min \left(|a|, |a|t\right)}{t} \, dt \\ &=\pi \int_{0}^{1} |a| \, dt \\ &= \pi |a|. \end{align}$$

Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(an)}{n} \right)^{2} = \pi |a|- \frac{a^{2}}{2}, \quad -\pi \le a \le \pi. $$

The convergence is indeed quite slow.

---

[The asymptotic expansion of the sine integral as $|z| \to \infty$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12#ii)

$(1)$ [How do I show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax) \sin(bx)}{x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx = \pi \min(a,b)/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441106)

---

The alternating version of your series, namely, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \left(\frac{\operatorname{Si(an)}}{n}\right)^{2}  $$ also has a simple closed-form expression for $- \frac{\pi}{2} \le a \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Specifically, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{\operatorname{Si(an)}}{n}\right)^{2} = \frac{a^{2}}{2} ,  \quad  -\frac{\pi}{2} \le a \le \frac{\pi}{2}. \tag{1}$$

What's particularly interesting about $(1)$ is that it remains true if $\operatorname{Si}(an)$ is replaced by $\sin(an)$.

To prove $(1)$, we can integrate the complex function $$f(z) = \pi \csc(\pi z) \left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(az)}{z}\right)^{2} $$ around a rectangular contour (call it $C_{N}$) with vertices at $\pm \left(N+ \frac{1}{2} \right)\pm i \left(N+ \frac{1}{2} \right)$, where $N$ is some positive integer.

Notice that except for a removable singularity at the origin, the function $\left( \frac{\operatorname{Si}(az)}{z} \right)^{2}$ is an analytic function on the entire complex plane.

So by integrating around the contour, and using the fact that $\pi \csc(\pi z)$ has simple poles at the integers with residues that alternate between $1$ and $-1$, we get $$\int_{C_{N}} f(z) \, dz = 2 \pi i \left(2 \sum_{n=1}^{N} (-1)^{n} \left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(az)}{z}\right)^{2}  + \operatorname{Res}[f(z), 0]\right), $$ where $$\operatorname{Res}[f(z),0] = \pi \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{\sin(\pi z)} \left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(az)}{z}\right)^{2} = \pi \left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right) \left(a^{2} \right) = a^{2}.$$

If we can  argue that $\csc(\pi z) \operatorname{Si}^{2}(ax)$ remains bounded on the contour as $N \to \infty$ through the positive integers, then it follows from the [estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) that $\int_{C_{N}} f(z) \, dz$ vanishes as $N \to \infty$.

The asymptotic expansion of the [sine integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.12#ii)  as $|z| \to \infty$ tells us that the magnitude of $\operatorname{Si}^{2}(az)$ eventually starts growing exponentially as $\operatorname{Im}(z) \to \pm \infty$.

But if $- \frac{\pi}{2} \le a \le \frac{\pi}{2}$, the exponential decay of the magnitude of $\csc(\pi z)$ as $\operatorname{Im}(z) \to \pm \infty$ counters this growth.

Therefore, if $\frac{\pi}{2} \le a \le \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{C_{N}} f(z) \, dz = 0 = 2 \pi i  \left(2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\left(\frac{\operatorname{Si}(az)}{z}\right)^{2}  + a^{2}\right),$$ and the result follows.

Alternatively, you could use the [alternating version of the Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula).