# Relation between logartihm and sine integral function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Prove that:

$$
-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\;\log(t)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}(1-\log(\pi))+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{Si(n\pi)}{n}\cos(nt)
$$
where $Si(x)$ denote the *sine integral function*, which is defined by:
$$Si(x)=\int_0^x \dfrac{\sin(u)}{u}du$$

**My work**: the sum term looks like a Fourier series of an even function, since:
$$
\dfrac{Si(n\pi)}{\pi n}=\int_0^1\dfrac{\sin(\pi n x)}{\pi nx}dx.
$$
Also, the Fourier series should be related with  the logarithm function, but compute it Fourier coefficients looks quite difficult.

Comment: I believe $sen$ should be $\sin$ in the second formula, and the third formula should be $\frac{\text{Si}(\pi n)}{\pi n}=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin (\pi n x)}{\pi  n x} \, dx$. I believe the Fourier series is valid for $0<t<\pi$.

Comment: Sorry, all of you are right. I just correct it.

Comment: Your third formula still has $\text{Si}$ instead of $\sin$ in the integrand on the right side.

Comment: consider the function $\log |t|, |t| < \pi, t \ne 0$ which is integrable and even so write its cosine Fourier series $n$th term and integrate by parts for $n \ge 1$ (which works as $\sin nt/t$ is integrable at $0$ while it's straight computation for $n=0$  and you get the (correct) result; or you can start with the Fourier stieltjes series of $1/t$ (which is not integrable at $0$ but is odd and has a sine Fourier stieltjes series because $\sin nt /t$ is integrable as above))  in terms of $\sin nt$ and integrate it term by term

Comment: Have a look to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2498250/305862).