# Does there exist a closed form for the sinc function series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\sqrt{n^2+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Here I want to get the closed form solution of the following summation

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\sqrt{n^2+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} \qquad(1)
$$

Or the more general form ($x$ be an arbitrary real number, and $a\geq0$ is a constant):

$$
f_a(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}\qquad(2)
$$

I tried the numeircal simulations before I post the question. I truncated the first $1,000,000$ terms of equation (1) and it turned $0.781233190560320$.

Anyone can help me?

In fact, I made it the reduced case when $a=0$. It can be proved by Fourier series:
$$
f_0(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \left\{ \matrix{\dfrac{\pi-x}{2}, 0<x<2\pi\\0, x=0,2\pi} \right. 
$$
And the function is periodical:
$$
f_0(x) = f_0(x+2\pi)
$$

**Edit**: How about this one?
$$
g_a(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}\qquad(3)
$$

We get the "diverging wave solution" in physics when we combine the equation (2) and (3):
$$
h_a(x)=g_a(x)+\text{i}f_a(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\exp\left(\text{i}x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}\qquad(4)
$$

**Edit #2**:
I tested the solution solved by *Random Variable* (see the most ranked answer and thousands thanks to it!) compared with the truncating results:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\sin \left(x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}, N = 1,000,000, a=1
$$

Here is the solution by *@Random Variable*:
the solution of equation (2) as the following:

> $$
> \sum_{n={1}}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}} 
> =
> \frac{\pi}{2} J_0(ax) -\frac{\sin(ax)}{2a}, a>0, 0<x<2\pi\qquad(2*)
> $$
>   where $J_0(ax)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero.

Here is the comparison:
[image]

> It can be found that the both agree well when $0 <x<2\pi$,but differ in other domain. So, how about the solution beyond $(0,2\pi)$?

**Edit #3**:

Inspired by *Random Variable*'s answer, I found the solution of equation (3) as the following:

> $$
> \sum_{n={1}}^\infty \frac{\cos\left(x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}} 
> =
> -\frac{\pi}{2} Y_0(ax) -\frac{\cos(ax)}{2a}, a>0, 0<x<2\pi\qquad(3*)
> $$
>   where $Y_0(ax)$ is the Bessel function of the second kind of order zero.

Here is the comparison:
[image]
**Note that equation (3) is divergent when $x=0$**.

---

Possible relating QUESTIONS:

[Does there exist a closed form for the non-integer shifted sinc-function series: $\frac{\sin(n+a)x}{(n+a)x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542240/does-there-exist-a-closed-form-for-the-non-integer-shifted-sinc-function-series/2542333#2542333)

Comment: It's equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{n^2+1}{k^2\pi^2}\right)$$ but I don't immediately see how that helps.

Comment: Does $(3*)$ seem to hold numerically? I wasn't sure if the Abel-Plana formula would be applicable due to the fact that $\frac{\cos(x \sqrt{z^{2}+a^{2}})}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a^{2}}} $ has branch points on the imaginary axis.

Comment: I just reasoned out the solution by analogy according to the equation 10.9.9 [HERE](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9#i). The numerical results does hold on $(-2\pi,2\pi)$!

Comment: There was a missing condition about the behavior of $f(z)$ as $\operatorname{Re}(z) \to +\infty$.  I'm not quite sure how to justify that the Abel-Plana formula is applicable here.  And the justification I used in my answer to that other question won't work here.

Comment: Do you have a link to the original question/answer? There's some context missing here

Comment: This is the original QUESTION. An answer post by @RandomVariable was deleted by himself

Comment: @Dylan I deleted my answer because I couldn't provide adequate justification.

Comment: @Dylan I rewrite the solution evolved by *@Random Variable*, which does agree well with the numerical results when $0<x<2\pi$. Then, how about the case when $x>2\pi$ and how to prove the solution.

Comment: That's a shame. I would've liked to see it.

Comment: Hi OP. Sorry to disturb you, but Paul Enta and I have discussed about [a problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364125/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin-leftx-sqrta2n2-right-left/3364254?noredirect=1#comment6925500_3364254) related to yours, and both of us have found discrepancy in numeric evidence and analytic value your formula offers. Precisely, it's about your formula $(3*)$. Would you please have a look at our discussion? (After all I've checked that Abel-Plana formula is also vaild in the cosine case, but didn't find any mistakes that can cause the difference)

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE**:

To apply the Abel-Plana formula, the behavior of $f(z)$ as $\Re (z) \to + \infty$ is also important. This was omitted from my answer.

A sufficient condition, now stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1596564),
is  $f(z) \sim O(e^{2\pi|\Im z|}/|z|^{1+\epsilon}) $ as $\Re(z) \to +\infty$.

The function $\frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{z^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a^{2}}} $ does not satisfy this condition.

But as **achille hui** explains in the linked answer, this condition is about ensuring  that $\lim_{b\to\infty} f(b) = 0$ and $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{f(b+it)-f(b-it)}{e^{2\pi t} - 1}dt = 0. $$

I've asked **achille hui** to post an answer to show that the limit of the above integral is indeed going to zero.

---

We can use the the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) as stated in **achille hui**'s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1596564).

First notice that the singularities of  $f(z) = \frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{z^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{z^{2}+a^{2}}}$ are removable.

Also, for $x>0$, $\left|\sin \left( x\sqrt{z^{2}+a^{2}}\right)\right| \sim \frac{e^{x\left|\Im (z)\right|}}{2} $as $\Im(z)  \to \pm \infty$.

So if $0 < x < 2 \pi$, the conditions of the Abel-Plana formula are satisfied, and we get
$$\begin{align} \sum_{{\color{red}{n=0}}}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{n^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{n^{2}+a^{2}}} &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}} \, dt + \frac{1}{2} f(0) + i (0) \\ &=  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}} \, dt +  \frac{\sin (ax)}{2a}. \end{align}$$

But from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1376461), we know that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} J_{0}(ax), \quad (a>0, \ x>0), \tag{1}$$ where $J_{0}(x)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero.

(To see that $(1)$ is related to the Mehler–Sonine integral representation of the Bessel function of the first kind, you only need to make the initial substitution in that answer).

Therefore, $$\sum_{{\color{red}{n=0}}}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{n^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{n^{2}+a^{2}}} =  \frac{\pi}{2} J_{0}(ax) + \frac{\sin (ax)}{2a}, \quad (a>0, \ 0<x < 2 \pi).$$

To recover the $a=0$ case, pull out the $n=0$ term and take the limit on both sides of the equation as $a \to 0^{+}$.

---

It should be noted that the series converges by Dirichlet's test since $$\sin \left( x\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}}\right) \sim \sin(tx) + \mathcal{O} \left(\frac{1}{t} \right)$$ as $t \to \infty$, which can be shown by expanding $\sqrt{t^{2}+a^{2}} = t \sqrt{1+ \frac{a^{2}}{t^{2}}}$ at $t= \infty$ and using the trig identity for $\sin(\alpha +\beta)$.

Comment: awesome, i wouldn't have bet a penny on a closed form but here we go....(+10)

Comment: it is interesting that $\sum...=\int...$ becomes exact for $x=k\pi/a$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: @tired  I could have evaluated that Bessel function series using the Abel-Plana formula, but at the time I didn't know that you could weaken the conditions. I think the proof would be similar to what I did in that answer. The contour would just be a bit different.

Comment: Impressive ... But it will take me some time to understand your answer... You may consider the other case as seen in my last edit.

Comment: What does the *growth conditions* mean?

Comment: @JiaxinZhong   As achille hui stated in the answer I linked to, one of the conditions that needs to be satisfied is $f(z) \sim o\left(e^{2\pi|\operatorname{Im}(z)|}\right)$ as $\operatorname{Im}(z) \to \pm \infty$, uniformly with respect to $\operatorname{Re}(z)$. If $f(z)$ grows any faster than that, than the formula is not applicable.  This is satisfied in our case if $-2 \pi < x < 2 \pi$. I purposely chose only $0< x< 2 \pi$ because $(1)$ is only valid of $x>0$.

Comment: @JiaxinZhong   BTW, since $\sin(x)$ is an odd function and $J_{0}(x)$ is an even function, it must be the case that  
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left( x\sqrt{n^{2}+a^{2}}\right)}{\sqrt{n^{2}+a^{2}}} =  -\frac{\pi}{2} J_{0}(ax) + \frac{\sin (ax)}{2a}, \quad (a>0,  -2 \pi  < x < 0). $$

Comment: @RandomVariable, Thanks! I'm now understand the conditions. But when $x>2\pi$, the conditions don't hold. So I'm still struggling about the case when $x>2\pi$. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @JiaxinZhong   I don't have any ideas at the moment.

Comment: @RandomVariable.See comment to you.

Comment: Beautiful solution! +1

Answer (score 6):

Per request, this is a supplement to Random Variable's answer.

In Frank W. J Olver's book: [Asymptotics and Special Functions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012525850X), the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) on finite sum appears in essentially following form:

> Let $S$ be the strip $a \le \Re z \le b$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$. For any function $f(z)$
>
> 1. continuous on $S$ and analytic on interior of $S$.
> 2. $f(z) \sim o(e^{2\pi|\Im z|} )$ as $\Im z \to \pm \infty$, uniformly with respect to $\Re z$.
>
> We have
>   $$\begin{align}\sum_{n=a}^b f(n) = &\int_a^b f(x) dx + \frac12\left( f(a) + f(b)\right) \\& + i \int_0^\infty \frac{f(a+it) - f(a-it) - f(b+it) + f(b-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1} dt\end{align}$$

For $f(z) = \frac{\sin(x\sqrt{z^2+a^2})}{\sqrt{z^2+a^2}}$ with $0 < x < 2\pi$, above conditions is satisfied for $a = 0$ and any $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. To obtain the version of AP formula for infinite sum used in Random Variable's answer, we just need:

$$\lim_{b\to \infty}f(b) = 0\quad\text{ and }\quad
\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{f(b+it) - f(b-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1} dt = 0$$
The first condition is trivial. For the second condition, notice for any $n > 0$,
$$\left|\sqrt{(n\pm it)^2+a^2}\right| 
= \left|\sqrt{(n \pm i(t+a))(n \pm i(t-a))}\right| \ge n$$
We find for large $b$ and $t$, 
$$\frac{\left|f(b\pm it)\right|}{e^{2\pi t}-1} \le
\frac{\left|\sin\left(x(b\pm it) + O\left(\frac{a^2}{b}\right)\right)\right|}{b(e^{2\pi t}-1)}
\sim \frac{1}{2b}e^{-(2\pi - x)t}\left( 1 + O\left(\frac{a^2}{b}\right)\right)
$$
For large $b$ but small $t$, we have
$$\frac{\left|f(b + it) - f(b - it)\right|}{e^{2\pi t}-1} \sim O\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)$$ 
instead (the pole at $t = 0$ from denominator is cancelled by the differences in numerator).

Combine these, we have following estimate of the integral appears in second condition:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(b+it)-f(b-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1} dt = O\left(\frac{1}{b(2\pi - x)}\right)$$
The second condition is satisfied and the use of AP formula in answering this question is justified.

Comment: Thanks for your supplement and concern!

Answer (score 3):

To go beyond the limitation $-2\pi<x<2\pi$ for the sine series, we can use the representation G&R (6.677.6) (or Ederlyi TI p.57 1.13.47)
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}=\int_0^x J_0\left( n\sqrt{x^2-t^2} \right)\cos at\,dt\tag{1}
\end{equation} 
valid for $x>0$. (For $x<0$, we will use the fact that the series is an odd function of $x$, as remarked by @RandomVariable).
The summation can be computed using the Schlömilch series (G&R 8.521.1):
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_0(nz)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{z}+2\sum_{m=1}^p\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2-4\pi^2m^2\pi^2}}
\end{equation} 
for $2p\pi<z<2(p+1)\pi$, which defines $p=\lfloor \frac{z}{2\pi}\rfloor$. Choosing $z=\sqrt{x^2-t^2}$, 
\begin{align}
S(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}\\
&=\int_0^x\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_0\left( n\sqrt{x^2-t^2} \right)\cos at\,dt\\
&=\int_0^x\left[-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-t^2}}+2\sum_{m=1}^{\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{x^2-t^2}}{2\pi}\rfloor}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-t^2-4\pi^2m^2\pi^2}}\right] \cos at\,dt\\
&=\int_0^x\left[-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-t^2}}\right]\cos at\,dt+2\sum_{1\le m< \lfloor \frac{x}{2\pi}\rfloor}\int_0^{\sqrt{x^2-4\pi^2m^2}}\frac{\cos at\,dt}{\sqrt{x^2-4\pi^2m^2-t^2}}
\end{align}
(The summation does not exist if $\lfloor \frac{x}{2\pi}\rfloor=0$). With the classic integral representation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\pi}{2}J_0(s)=\int_0^1\frac{\cos sx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
\end{equation} 
the result can be written as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin x\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}J_0(ax)-\frac{\sin ax}{2a}+\pi\sum_{1\le m< \lfloor \frac{x}{2\pi}\rfloor}J_0\left( a\sqrt{x^2-4\pi^2m^2-t^2}\right)
\end{equation} 
which seems to be numerically correct. Unfortunately, no corresponding form of (1) for the cosines seems to exist.

Comment: Great. This is more of a complete answer compared to others.

Answer (score 0):

**COMMENT** to users: [Achille-Hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui) and [Random-Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16033/random-variable)

How about this ?:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(x \sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}=\frac{1}{2} \pi  J_0(a x)+\frac{\sin (a x)}{2 a}$$

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{\sin \left(x \sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}\right](s)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  J_0(a x)+\frac{\sin (a x)}{2 a}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{a^2+n^2+s^2}\right](x)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  J_0(a x)+\frac{\sin (a x)}{2 a}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{2 \left(a^2+s^2\right)}+\frac{\pi  \sqrt{-a^2-s^2} \cot \left(\pi  \sqrt{-a^2-s^2}\right)}{2 \left(a^2+s^2\right)}\right](x)=\frac{1}{2}
   \pi  J_0(a x)+\frac{\sin (a x)}{2 a}$$

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{2 \left(a^2+s^2\right)}\right](x)+\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[-\frac{\pi  \cot \left(\pi  \sqrt{-a^2-s^2}\right)}{2
   \sqrt{-a^2-s^2}}\right](x)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  J_0(a x)+\frac{\sin (a x)}{2 a}$$

for $a>0$ and $s>0$

$$\frac{\sin (a x)}{2 a}+\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\pi  \coth \left(\pi  \sqrt{a^2+s^2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{a^2+s^2}}\right](x)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  J_0(a x)+\frac{\sin (a x)}{2
   a}$$
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\pi  \coth \left(\pi  \sqrt{a^2+s^2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{a^2+s^2}}\right](x)=\frac{1}{2} \pi  J_0(a x)$$

$$\mathcal{L}_x\left[\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{\pi  \coth \left(\pi  \sqrt{a^2+s^2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{a^2+s^2}}\right](x)\right](s)=\mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{1}{2} \pi 
   J_0(a x)\right](s)$$

$$\frac{\pi  \coth \left(\pi  \sqrt{a^2+s^2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{a^2+s^2}}\neq \frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{a^2+s^2}}$$

and then:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(x \sqrt{n^2+a^2}\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}}\neq \frac{1}{2} \pi  J_0(a x)+\frac{\sin (a x)}{2 a}$$

**EDITED:**

Comparison  a numeric InverseLaplaceTransform and Bessel function:

[image]

Comment: OP's simulation already tell us $f_a(x) \ne \frac12\pi J_0(ax) + \frac{\sin(ax)}{2a}$ outside the interval $(0,2\pi)$. If you want to show this also fails for $x \in (0,2\pi)$, what you have done is not enough, you need to compute the Laplace transform with functions clipped within $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @achillehui.Yes you're right is true only in interval `0<x<2*Pi`

Comment: Thanks for your concerns!