# Improper integral of $\sin t/t$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof for an integral involving sinc function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-for-an-integral-involving-sinc-function)

Prove that:
$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin t}{t}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\sin^{2}t}{t^{2}}dt$

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange Lilly. In the future, please avoid using imperative language- rather than saying "Prove X" phrase it as "Can someone help me prove X? Here is what I've tried, but I got stuck here...". Members here will give you more help if you do that. Anyway, for your problem, you should try integrating by parts.

Comment: I don't know much about this subject, but I think you should take a look at this [reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html). (which defines the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{sin t}{t} dt$)

Comment: The indefinite integral corresponding to the right side can be expressed in terms of the indefinite integral corresponding to the left side.

Answer (score 14):

Integrating by parts:

$$\eqalign{
\int_0^\infty {\sin^2 t\over t^2}\,dt&= {-\sin^2 t\over t}\biggl|_0^\infty +
\int_0^\infty{ 2\sin t\cos t\over t}\,dt\cr
&={-\sin^2 t\over t}\biggl|_0^\infty +
\int_0^\infty{ 2 \sin 2t \over 2t}\,dt\cr
&= 0 + \int_0^\infty {\sin u\over u}\,du
}
$$

In the above, we computed $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0^+}{\sin^2 t\over t}=\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0^+}{2\sin  t \cos t\over 1}=0$; and in the last integral, we set $u=2t$.