# How to integrate $\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}?$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof for an integral involving sinc function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-for-an-integral-involving-sinc-function)

How can one calculate $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} dx$? I know that the answer is $\pi/2$ and I imagine we need to use complex analysis, but I'm not sure how to recast it into a contour integral appropriately.

Comment: Integrate by parts to see it is equal to $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx.$ To integrate that use the standard semi-circular contour.

Comment: This can actually also be done without contour integration: $\sin(x)/x$ is (up to a factor) the Fourier transform of $\chi_{[-1,1]}$. You can then use Parseval's identity to evaluate your integral.

Comment: @Sam L. One sledgehammer changed to another.

Comment: @Norbert: Fair enough, but at least two sledge hammers is an improvement on just the one. =)