# Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman! $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2(1+x^2)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> **Prove the following**
> \begin{equation}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2(1+x^2)}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4e^2}\end{equation}

I would love to see how Mathematics SE users prove the integral preferably with the Feynman way (other methods are welcome). Thank you. (>‿◠)✌

---

**Original question:**

> *And of course, for the sadist with a background in differential
> equations, I invite you to try your luck with the last integral of the
> group*.
>
> \begin{equation}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2(1+x^2)}\,dx\end{equation}

**Source:** [Integration: The Feynman Way](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffy.chalmers.se%2F%7Etfkhj%2FFeynmanIntegration.pdf&ei=i4V8U4a-Fc7LrQeXj4CgDQ&usg=AFQjCNFJumeh03nRgny3U_fUKVSxsy8ucw&sig2=IfbVwpP8Dcgw4vbfSVNiIg)

Comment: The antiderivative of  $\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2(1+x^2)}$ can be established analytically.

Comment: I'd love to see your claim Mr. @ClaudeLeibovici (ô‿ô)

Comment: This is not a claim at all. May be you could try Wolfram Alpha. The result is not so complex. I suppose that you will get goods answers. By the way, your attempts are very nice. Cheers.

Comment: I meant 'your attempt', please forgive my rudeness. Thank you so much Mr. @ClaudeLeibovici (^‿^ʃƪ)

Comment: Please, do not apologize for anything. I did not take the word in any bad way ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Cheers. ≥Ö‿Ö≤

Comment: "The Feynman way" is just a fancy name for the good old differentiation under the integral?

Comment: @DanielFischer I know that Sir but I prefer naming "The Feynman Way" (ô‿ô)

Comment: I wasn't sure, I was asking for confirmation.

Comment: @DanielFischer "The Feynman way" = the differentiation under integral sign

Comment: @DanielFischer: there seems to be a tendency on this site to label any differentiation of an artificially introduced parameter under the integral sign as "Feynman's <method, way, etc.>."  I doubt Feynman invented it, but I see that loads of people read "Surely You're Joking...".

Comment: @RonGordon Indeed. It's a good read, by the way. Now, will you have lemon or milk in your tea?

Comment: Mr. @RonGordon: There is a statement in the paper I linked that states, "the technique of “Feynman Integration” is a simple application of a theorem attributed to Leibniz". I'm quite sure Feynman does not invent this method. BTW, is it okay if I challenge you to answer my question? I know you have a really good reputation in solving integration questions on this site. **P.S.** Please don't take my challenge to you in any bad way. (>‿◠)✌

Comment: @V-Moy: Hey, I never said it was wrong; I just think it is a little funny.  BTW it would not be the first time that a method or something else is named after its popularizer rather than its inventor.

Comment: Aye Ron, L'Hopital's rule comes to mind.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This integral is readily evaluated using Parseval's theorem for Fourier transforms.  (I am certain that Feynman had this theorem in his tool belt.)  Recall that, for transform pairs $f(x)$ and $F(k)$, and $g(x)$ and $G(k)$, the theorem states that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) g^*(x) = \frac1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, F(k) G^*(k) $$

In this case, $f(x) = \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2}$ and $g(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$.  Then $F(k) = \pi (1-|k|/2) \theta(2-|k|)$ and $G(k) = \pi \, e^{-|k|}$. ($\theta$ is the Heaviside function, $1$ when its argument is positive, $0$ when negative.)  Using the symmetry of the integrand, we may conclude that

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2 (1+x^2)} &= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{2} dk \, \left ( 1-\frac{k}{2} \right ) e^{-k} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \left (1-\frac1{e^2} \right ) - \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^{2} dk \, k \, e^{-k} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \left (1-\frac1{e^2} \right ) + \frac{\pi}{2 e^2}  - \frac{\pi}{4} \left (1-\frac1{e^2} \right )\\ &= \frac{\pi}{4} \left (1+\frac1{e^2} \right )\end{align} $$

Comment: Amazing! I've just challenged you but you gave me an answer within a second. Awesome! d(ô‿ô)b

Comment: @V-Moy: Yeah, I'm fast like that.

Comment: Surely You're Joking, Mr. Gordon! （‐＾▽＾‐）

Comment: BTW, could you provide me links to learn about your method? It seems you take your answer to the level that I don't even know yet. (─‿‿─)

Comment: @V-Moy: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlancherelsTheorem.html Mathematicians refer to this as Plancherel's theorem and reserve Parseval for Fourier series.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Gordon. I guess I need days to learn it. BTW, +1 for your answer and thank you for answering my question. (^‿^ʃƪ)

Comment: @RonGordon, The fouriertransform of the $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ function, or rather $\operatorname{sinc}^2(x)$ have you calculated this earlier? If it is not too much to ask I would love a refference or link =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: because I am pressed for time, here's a WA link.  I will provide a full derivation as soon as I can.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierTransform%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5E2%2Fx%5E2%2Cx%2Ck%2CFourierParameters-%3E%7B1%2C-1%7D%5D&t=crmtb01

Comment: @RonGordon Why did you answer the same question again since you knew it was a duplicate?  You have already answered this question for me : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691798/differentiation-wrt-parameter-int-0-infty-sin2x-cdotx2x21-1dx.

Comment: @Integrals: because I answered it **three months ago** and at my age, dementia sets in.  I admit that sometimes I just answer the question without looking back through my vast database of answers.  So, no, I did not know it was a duplicate.

Comment: @RonGordon That makes sense since you answer a lot, however you still could have at flagged it as a duplicate question.

Comment: @Integrals: I would have if I had known.  But so what - the worst thing in the world is that duplicate correct (and consistent) answers exist in the site?  Vote to close as a duplicate if this bothers you.

Comment: You got the best profile pic on stack overflow. Man yells at cloud ahahaha

Answer (score 38):

Here is my attempt:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2(1+x^2)}dx&=\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}-\frac{\sin^2x}{1+x^2}\right]dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos2x}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos2x}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{2e^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4e^2}
\end{align}
where I use these links: [$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13344/133248) and [$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos2x}{1+x^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9402/133248) to help me out.

Unfortunately, this is not the Feynman way but I still love this method.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my answer @MycrofD. I'm too excited so I forgot about my English grammar. ≥Ö‿Ö≤

Comment: Next time put your attempt in the question. Besides, you got it right (>‿◠)✌.

Comment: @Shahar Thanks, +1 for your emo. ≧◠◡◠≦✌

Comment: @V-Moy You seem to be an expert in emo's and integrals. ✌

Comment: @Sawarnik You might say I'm expert in emo but not in integral, not yet (✿◠‿◠)

Comment: @V-Moy duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691798/differentiation-wrt-parameter-int-0-infty-sin2x-cdotx2x21-1dx

Comment: @Integrals Yeah I know that but why the number of upvote for each answer and the question decreases by 1 after my question is marked as DUPLICATE??

Comment: Nice answer. +1 before I go to sleep. Hope things are well. Haven't seen you on the chat in a while. (^‿^)/

Answer (score 31):

Consider 
$$
I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(ax)}{x^2(x^2+1)}dx
$$
Differentiate it twice. [Since](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/calculating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-mathrmdx-wit?lq=1)
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{x^2+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{2e^k}
$$
for $k>0$ we get $I''(a)=\pi e^{-2a}$. Note that $I'(0)=I(0)=0$, so after solving respective IVP we get
$$
I(a)=\frac{\pi}{4}(-1+2a+e^{-2a})
$$
Now it only remains to substitute for $a=1$.

Comment: Wait a second! Why never cross to mind to use Feynman method twice?? +1 Sir! ≥►.◄≤

Comment: @V-Moy Because you're not thinking like Feynman! Suppose the Feynman method just transforms your complicated integral into another complicated integral. Well, what tricks do you know for handling complicated integrals? That's right, the Feynman method! :)

Comment: Thanks for your advice Mr. @DavidH. I'll try to think like Feynman. I have a lot of time though. ᕙ(^▽^)ᕗ

Comment: Why did you post this solution again?  You knew this was a duplicate, this is a great solution but still.  -1. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691798/differentiation-wrt-parameter-int-0-infty-sin2x-cdotx2x21-1dx

Comment: @Integrals because it is not forbidden, and this answer perfectly fits to the question even more than the in the link you gave above.

Comment: @Norbert Please see MSE policy on duplicates.  Also I'm not sure what you mean,  "even more than the in the link..."?  Thanks a lot for your comments.  The question has been properly marked as a duplicate now.