# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2(x^2+1)} dx$ =?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

After reading articles on differentiation under the integral sign, I hit [this post](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf) from MIT OCW, where after introducing the power tool, it challenges reader to do

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2(x^2+1)} dx$$

Obviously I have no clue where to start. Could any one give a hint?

Comment: I think you can simplify first the integral using partial fractions since $\frac{1}{x^2 \left(x^2+1\right)}=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$. The first integral is simple; the second one is more problematic to me. Good luck.

Comment: The definite integral of $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ is simple: it is $\arctan(x)$. Remember that $\arctan(0)=0$ and $\arctan(\infty)=\pi/2$.

Comment: This question is the same as the problem in this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691798/differentiation-wrt-parameter-int-0-infty-sin2x-cdotx2x21-1dx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible way to evaluate the integral. Partial fraction decomposition and the double angle formula yield
$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2(1+x^2)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos{2x}}{x^2}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos{2x}}{1+x^2}dx$$
The first integral can be evaluated in many ways, differentiation under the integral sign is one of them. I prefer to proceed with a simple fact that follows from the definition of the gamma function.
$$\int^{\infty}_0t^{n-1}e^{-xt} \ dt=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{x^n}$$
Hence the first integral is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos{2x}}{x^2}dx
&=\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0(1-\cos{2x})\int^\infty_0te^{-xt} \ dt \ dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0t\int^\infty_0e^{-xt}(1-\cos{2x}) \ dx \ dt\\
&=\int^\infty_0\left(\int^\infty_0e^{-xt}\sin{2x} \ dx\right)dt\\
&=\int^\infty_0\frac{2}{t^2+4}dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{align}
The second integral can be broken up further and evaluated using the residue theorem.
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0\frac{1-\cos{2x}}{1+x^2}dx
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\Re\oint_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{2iz}}{1+z^2}dz\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\Re\left(\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,i)\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\Re\left(\pi i\frac{e^{-2}}{2i}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4e^2}
\end{align}
Hence
$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2(1+x^2)}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1+e^{-2}\right)$$

Comment: thanks a lot and.. the trick with $\int^{\infty}_0t^{n-1}e^{-xt} \ dt=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{x^n}$ is brilliant! i only saw $n=1$ case before, never realized that could utilize $n>1$!

Answer (score 7):

> *Could any one give a hint?*

[Partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), together with the fact that

- $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}dx=\frac\pi2$
- $\sin^2x=\dfrac{1-\cos2x}2$
- $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac\pi{2a~e^a}$

Answer (score 1):

We first split the integral into two as

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2 x}{x^2\left(1+x^2\right)} d x=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2 x}{x^2} d x-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2 x}{1+x^2} d x
$$

---

For the first one, we can use  integration by parts and double integral.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2 x}{x^2} d x & =\int_0^{\infty} \sin ^2 x d\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2 x)}{x} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x t} \sin x d t d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x t} \sin x d x d t \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^2+1} d t \\
& =\left[\tan ^{-1} t\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}$$

---

For the second integral, we use contour integration by the path $\gamma$ in anti-clockwise direction.

$$ \gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi). $$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2 x}{1+x^2} d x&=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos 2 x}{1+x^2} d x \\& =\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2 x}{1+x^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos 2 x}{1+x^2} d x&=\frac{1}{2} \Re \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2 x i}}{1+x^2} d x \\& =\frac{1}{2} \Re\left(\lim _{R \rightarrow \infty} \oint_\gamma \frac{e^{2 z i}}{1+z^2} d x\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \Re\left(2 \pi i \lim _{z \rightarrow i} \frac{e^{-2}}{2 i}\right)\\&=\frac{\pi}{2 e^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Now we can conclude
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^2 x}{x^2\left(1+x^2\right)} d x
=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(1+\frac{1}{e^2}\right)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Fourier transform

The integral can be seen as a Fourier transform:
$$
I := \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2(x^2+1)} \, dx
= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{1}{x^2+1} e^{-i0x} \, dx
\\
= \frac12 \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \frac{1}{x^2+1} \}(0)
.
$$

By the duality of product and convolution under Fourier transform we can rewrite this as
$$
I = 
= \frac12 \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2} \left(\mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \} * \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \} * \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{1}{x^2+1} \} \right)(0)
.
$$

Now,
$$
\mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \} = \pi\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]}(\xi),
$$
where $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the indicator function on the set $A,$
and
$$
\mathcal{F}\{ \frac{1}{x^2+1} \} = \pi e^{-|\xi|}
.
$$

Thus,
$$
I = \frac{1}{8\pi^2} \left( \pi\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * \pi\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * \pi e^{-|\bullet|} \right)(0)
\\
= \frac{\pi}{8} \left( \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * e^{-|\bullet|} \right)(0)
.
$$

Here,
$$
(\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]})(x) = (2-|x|) \, \mathbf{1}_{[-2,2]}(x)
$$
so
$$
\left( \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * e^{-|\bullet|} \right)(\xi)
= \int_{-2}^{2} (2-|\eta|) e^{-|\xi-\eta|} \, d\eta
$$
However, we only need to calculate this at $\xi=0$:
$$
I = \left( \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} * e^{-|\bullet|} \right)(0)
= \int_{-2}^{2} (2-|\eta|) e^{-|\eta|} \, d\eta
= 2 \int_{0}^{2} (2-\eta) e^{-\eta} \, d\eta = 2 (1 + e^{-2}).
$$

Thus, finally,
$$
I = \frac{\pi}{8}\cdot 2 (1 + e^{-2}) = \frac{\pi}{4}(1 + e^{-2}).
$$