# Are there elementary ways to proof $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \mathrm{d}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Is there an elementary way to proof  that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \mathrm{d}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ or equivalently
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \mathrm{d}{x} = \pi \;\;\; \text{?}$$

**Prequesites (which might be assumed):**

1. Basic knowledge about limits, complex numbers, differentiation, series and power series as well as indefinite Riemann-integration in one dimension may be assumed (including Riemann-sums).
2. No complex or multi-dimensional calculus as well as Fourier-analysis.

**Note (1):**

Sorry if the question is covered somewhere already I couldn't find it. Also it is absolutely clear that the integral can be solved by a multitude of approaches if the prerequisites are dropped among them fourier analysis, polar coordinates and complex analysis.

**Note (2):**
The closest thing I found was a combination of Robin Chapman's [Approach 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13362/167444) and Zarax's method used in [Approach 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13348/167444). This essentially reduces to first showing by integration by parts that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \mathrm{d}{x} = S \Longleftrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2} \mathrm{d}{x} = S$$
and then showing that 
$$ S =  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2} \mathrm{d}{x} = \pi$$
as described in [Approach 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13362/167444).
Which is what I will post as  fleshed out answer later.

**Note (3):**
For completness sake possible solutions to the problem are already collected in [Solving the dirichlet Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2) but as stated in the comments I was looking for something more basic.

Nevertheless any other basic approaches (not already collected there) are highly welcome!

Comment: Are you ok with differentiation under the integral sign?

Comment: Interchange of limits/differentiation and integrals should be okay as long as you do not need multivariate calculus (i.e. interchange of integrations). In other words one can assume that uniform convergence is a known concept.

Comment: I'm aware of most of the answers given in: [Alex Silva's Ref](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2). From them only three or four come within the range of what I'm looking for: [No. 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/5322/167444), [No. 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/5319/167444), [No. 3](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/8350/167444) and a duplicate of mrf's answer [No.4](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/328403/167444). But basically I was hoping for something even more basic.

Comment: Oh, was there an duplicate there? I scrolled through it and couldn't find one. I missed that one. I should probably delete mine then.