# Calculate integral using Dirichlet integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} \left(\frac{\sin \alpha x}{x}\right)^3\,dx,
$$
using the Dirichlet integral:
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin \alpha x}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{sgn}\,\alpha.
$$

It seems to me, that there exists some substitution.

Comment: see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-of-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-xx-right2-mathrm-dx-frac-pi2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exploiting $3\sin z-\sin(3z)=4\sin^3 z$ and integrating by parts twice,
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^3(\alpha x)}{x^3}\,dx = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{3\alpha^2\sin(\alpha x)+9\alpha^2\sin(3\alpha x)}{x}\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{3\pi \alpha^2}{8}\text{Sign}(\alpha)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

A clumsy way is to really calculate that:

$$\int u dv = u v -\int v du$$

So

$$\int (\frac{\sin \alpha x}{x})^3 dx = (\frac{\sin \alpha x}{x})^3 -\int x d((\frac{\sin \alpha x}{x})^3) dx =(\frac{\sin \alpha x}{x})^3-\int\frac{3x}{-x^2} (\alpha x \cos \alpha x - 1 \times sin \alpha x )(\frac{\sin \alpha x}{x})^2 dx$$

and so on ...