# Evaluating the integral: $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\right)^2 dx , a \neq 0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Integrate from 0 to infinity
>   $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\right)^2  dx , a \neq 0  $$

I tried evaluating the indefinite integral of that function using Sine integral. But I failed to do it. I am having no idea to evaluate the definite integral. I seek for help

Comment: By the tagging I'm afraid not, but: can you use complex analysis? In particular, complex integration?

Comment: You didn't understand: I meant **complex analysis*, like with "complex numbers"...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh yes complex analysis is required, but I think that will be complicated so any idea to develop the result using series?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes i accepted the answer below

Comment: Well, that means you've already solved your problem with Guy's answer. Good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First from here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508827 it is easy to prove  using  the changes $u=2y$ that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u}dx= \int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(u)}{u}\right)^2dx$$

Inserting the change of variables $u=ax$ one gets

$$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}\right)^2dx = a\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\right)^2d(ax)\\= a \operatorname{sign}(a)\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin(u)}{u}\right)^2dx =|a|\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u}dx =\color{blue}{\frac{|a|π}{2} }$$

this comes from the Dirichlet integral [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \ dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2)

Comment: Why "a sign(a)" instead of simply $\,|a|\;$ ? And the rightmost integral looks as messy as the original one. I mean, if the OP knows that then the integral in the question doesn't look that hard.

Comment: @Guy Fsone Can you elaborate the reason for asign(pi/2) how did u get that?

Comment: @DonAntonio  it takes the value 1 for $a>0$ and -1 for  $a<0$ and 0 for $a=0$

Comment: @GuyFsone I know that, but then "a sign(a)" is *exactly the same* as $\;|a|\;$ ...and indeed the solution to this integral is $\;\cfrac{\pi|a|}2\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks very much for the remark it is true

Comment: @Guy Fsone Thank you for wonderfully analysing the problem

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\int\frac{\sin^2(ax)}{x^2} d x = - \frac{\sin^2(a x)}{x} + \int \frac{2a \sin(a x)\cos(a x)}{x} d x$$

and $2 a\sin(a x)\cos(a x) = a \sin(2 a x)$

Comment: How is it going to help the OP to attempt to solve $\;\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{a\sin2ax}x\mathrm dx\;$ ? Is this integral easier in any way than the original one?

Comment: @Gribouillis I done till this, but after this i need to prove Guy Fsone's answer

Comment: It is one change of variable away from a known integral.

Comment: @TobErnack If you mean the integral of $\;\sin x/x\;$ , the question is: "known integral"...for whom? Apparently not the OP...

Comment: Right I guess I assumed they knew that one and wanted to reduce their problem to it.

Comment: @TobErnack That's probably true, though. Observe the OP's already accepted the first answer...

Comment: Well, at least this explain why the original integral reduces to Dirichlet's integral, which solution is already on this site.