# Integrating $\arccos(x)$ with the residue theorem

Tags: definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Considering $\arccos(x)=-i\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$, which has branch points at $1$, $-1$, and infinity, it seems natural to attempt evaluating $$\int\limits^{1}_{-1}\arccos(x)dx$$ using the residue theorem. I tried and it didnt seem to work; can this actually be done, and if so how? If not, why?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You don't need the residue theorem, you can integrate by parts.

Comment: @sammygerbil I tried a dogbone since I couldn't reason out how to work with the logarithm. Thinking about it now, it seems the logarithm could be the problem.

Comment: @Wrench I am aware, I just wanted to see if this could be done with the residue theorem so I could apply a similar method to similar integrands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\arccos(z)$, the points $z=1, z=-1$ are **branch points**, no good for computing via the residue theorem.  When this happens, we may sometimes evaluate by finding the residues **outside** the contour.  But there the point $z=\infty$ is also a branch point, so we still cannot use the residue theorem.

However, $\arccos z - i\log z$ (with the appropriate branches of $\arccos$ and $\log$) is single-valued at $z=\infty$, with residue $0$, so for a contour $\gamma$ that surrounds both $1$ and $-1$ once in the clockwise direction,

[image: coutour]

we get $\oint_\gamma \arccos z\;dz = \oint_\gamma i\log z\;dz = 2 \pi$.  The limit of this branch of $\arccos z$ approaching the real axis from below is $\arccos x$, but
the limit approaching from above is $-\arccos x$.  So
$$
2\pi = \int_1^{-1} (-\arccos x)\;dx + \int_{-1}^1 \arccos  x\;dx
= 2\int_{-1}^1 \arccos x
$$
Therefore our answer is $\pi$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. My error was taking the residue at infinity. Thank you!

Comment: Does the arccosine function have branch points at $0$ and $\infty$?

Comment: The arccosine has branch points at $1,-1,\infty$.  But it is regular at $0$.