# Can the integral of $x^x$ be found?

Tags: calculus, limits, integration, derivatives

I'm interested in knowing if the indefinite integral of $x^x$ can be found in terms of elementary functions.

I am under the impression (be it correct or incorrect) that it can be found. This is why: the derivative of $x^x$ has $x^x$ in it ($d/dx[x^x] = x^x(\ln(x) + 1)$). The derivative is quite easy to find with logarithmic differentiation, but the integral – not so much.

If the indefinite integral cannot be defined in terms of elementary functions, why?

If the indefinite integral can be found, would you please work it out? I find myself lost here, I've tried multiple methods.

Comment: Go to wolframalpha.com, enter something like int(x^x,x) into the box, and see what happens.  I would guess that if it gives any answer it will be in terms of special functions (not elementary functions).

Comment: It can't see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265780/how-to-determine-with-certainty-that-a-function-has-no-elementary-antiderivative).

Comment: Let $F(x) = \int x^x\,\mathrm dx$. Then $F'(x)=x^x$. Let's make the ansatz $F(x) = x^x f(x)$. Then $F'(x) = x^x((1+\ln x)f(x) + f'(x))$. Therefore $f(x)$ should solve the differential equation $f'(x) + (1+\ln x)f(x) = 1$. Unfortunately I have no idea how you would solve that differential equation.

Comment: This function has no elementary antiderivative. Of course, it can be integrated numerically over given intervals (using a series expansion or other methods). This is a famous example. See [here](http://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/wiener-elemint.pdf).

Comment: There are a few questions on this site listing references on this topic, for example [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/287442/462).

Comment: Your impression is based on a bad analogy between the simplicity of the derivative and that of the integral.  It is essentially the same as claiming that, since $1/x$ is easy to differentiate as a rational function, it must also be easy to integrate as one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x^x=e^{x \ln x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x \ln x)^k}{k!}$. Then interchange the integral sign and summation sign.

Comment: maybe you will find it useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream

Comment: I've tried integrating e^xln(x) multiple times, but I haven't gotten very far. The summation method may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I remember doing a STEP question, which basically lead to solving this integral http://www.mathshelper.co.uk/STEP%20III%202009.pdf q8.

Answer (score 1):

No, $\int x^x\;dx$ is not an elementary function.