# Amazing integrals and how is solved it

Tags: integration, soft-question, big-list

There a lot of  integrals, however many people solved it in different ways, we can find interesting integrals in [Table of Integrals, Series, and Products](http://www.mathtable.com/gr/). I wonder What is the most exciting integral that you solved, created or found it, if you can, also write the solution of the integral, we can find very nicely methods.

Comment: I recently found a nice little book by V.H. Moll, [Special Integrals of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik: the Proofs](https://books.google.hr/books?id=dRYeBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA231&lpg=PA231&dq=Victor+Moll+integrals+in+gradshteyn&source=bl&ots=Y5fGqpxXRx&sig=E4KLHJhJhgn-mQ-IWwe08LnKCSo&hl=hr&sa=X&ei=5UI3VfbxLNL1arTtgdgB&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Victor%20Moll%20integrals%20in%20gradshteyn&f=false). I think you'd like it very much, it basically covers exactly what you're asking!

Comment: @krvolok Nice!, This book is also awesome: [Inside Interesting Integrals](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781493912766), but if you have a favorite integral, please write it.

Comment: @krvolok Nice book! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{x^2+1}$$ I really like this. It seems to be posted again and again. Solutions can be found here: [Evaluate the integral: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-mathrm-dx)