# Integral of $e^{y^2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Why can't be we take the antiderivative of $e^{y^2}$ with respect to y? My textbook just says it is not possible. That's it. No explanation. I could not find any one explanation on the web where it was explained either. Might seem like a dorky question but any explanation would be appreciated. But if we can, I guess the next natural question would be, "what is the anti-derivative?"

Comment: You absolutely can, there's just no closed form way of expressing it.

Comment: Well, we can, but the result is not an *elementary function*, that is, a combination of the standard functions that we know and love.

Comment: What textbook is this?

Comment: The reason your book does not explain anything about the proof is that it really is beyond the level of a calculus textbook. For a quick sketch of the relevant mathematics, see [this note](http://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/wiener-elemint.pdf) by Matthew Wiener. [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/359014/462) has additional references, and quite a few problems on this site are relevant as well. The key phrase is "elementary integration."

Comment: If you've had power series already, write out the general term for $ \ e^{x^2} \ $ and integrate it term-by-term.  Does the resulting series resemble anything related to the elementary functions that you know?  Instead, we simply define a new (non-elementary) function which is described by that series, as described by **rghthndsd** below.  (In fact, many useful ("special") functions are defined by such integrals...)

Answer (score 5):

Brian Conrad has [this article](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf) going through what it means to say an integral is "impossible", among other things. However it is rather on the advanced side.

As for the anti-derivative, it is defined to be $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erfi}(y)+C$. You can see a graph of this function at [wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+e%5E%28y%5E2%29).

Comment: In reality Brian Conrad article gives an "elementary" proof (modulo the language) of that impossibility. In particular he *does not* use differential Galois theory. I think in principle an ambitious freshmen could go through his proof (in reality of course some field theory would be nice).

Answer (score 1):

G. H. Hardy's [The Integration of Functions of a Single Variable](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/38993) (second edition (1916), *gratis* download from Project Gutenberg) may be of interest as a readable exposition.

(He cites theorems of Liouville that imply $\int e^{x^2}\, dx$ cannot be expressed in elementary terms (pp. 62 *ff.*), so this reference is not a complete answer to the original question.)