# How to prove $\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \ dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2)

How to prove $$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Do you have a simple method ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5248/23784

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the Dirichlet integral. A couple of different derivations appear on the Wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral#Evaluation