# What is the indefinite integral of the function $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus

I want to know if the function $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is integrable and if it is, then what's its integral?

My high school book says its a non-integrable function while WolframAlpha says its integral is Si$(x) +$constant.

Please shed some light on this topic and explain from basic level like what is Si$(x)$, who used it for the first time etc.

Comment: The *indefinite* integral, you mean. Of course, $\mathrm{Si}(x)$ is simply *defined* to be a definite integral of $(\sin x)/x$, so of course you're going to get this plus a constant.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral) for the definition of $\operatorname{Si}(x)$.

Comment: you can see these links and you should know that your question is related to advanced math http://calculus-geometry.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Integrate-sinxx-and-cosxx
http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=sin%28x%29%2Fx&random=false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \ dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no [elementary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) whose derivative is $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.  However, antiderivatives of this function come up moderately frequently in applications, for example in signal processing. So it has been convenient to give one of its antiderivatives, $\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$, a name. The standard name is $\text{Si}(x)$. In the old days, one could find tables of $\text{Si}(x)$. Nowadays, it is a built-in function in many programs, including *Maple* and *Mathematica*.

There are many other instances in mathematics where a non-elementary function has been given a special name.  So there is an enormous variety of such *special function*, among them the *error* function of probability theory, and the *Gamma function*.

**Remark:** If you write down a medium-ugly elementary function, like $\frac{e^x}{x^2+1}$, or even $\sqrt{1+x+x^5}$, the function will usually not have an *elementary* antiderivative.  this makes for real trouble when we are trying to invent new arclength problems. Recall that the arclength of $y=f(x)$ involves $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\,dx$. If we start with a quite nice function $f(x)$, the function $\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$ can be pretty complicated, and ordinarily does not have an elementary antiderivative. That's why most of the calculus book examples in the arclength section are quite artificial.

Answer (score 5):

In general, a function $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable if it is bounded and the set of discontinuities (i.e. $x=0$ in this case) have measure zero.  Intuitively, this more or less amounts to the function being defined except at reasonably few exceptional points (i.e. a finite number of points as in this case is fine), so the function is integrable since it is clearly also bounded.  As the others have mentioned and linked to, the integral is nontrivial and has a special function defined to be its antiderivative called $Si(x)$.