# how to integrate $\int \frac{\sin x}{x}$ in $[0,1]$

Tags: improper-integrals

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with this problem
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx$$
here using Taylor series I got   $\sum_{0}^{\infty} $$\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!(2n+1)} $ then what to do? is it the final answer ? please explain

Comment: So this is a problem from the book where you are supposed to find the exact value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the integral of function $f(x) = (\sin x)/x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163305/what-is-the-integral-of-function-fx-sin-x-x)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first expand $\frac {\sin x} x$ as a Taylor series and then integrate that, or you can check out this link:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html

Comment: That's $\large {\rm Si}\left(1\right)$ where $\large{\rm Si}\left(z\right)$ is the [Sine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) function.