# Compute the integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ .

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

How to compute precisely the integral $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$$ analytically? It is well-known that $$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$ One way to compute the above integral using Taylor expansion for $\sin x$, we then obtain a power series value approximately 1.84. Thanks for any useful hints.

Comment: Apart from writing it's $\mathrm{Si}(\pi)$, where $\mathrm{Si}$ is [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html), you can't do much.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163305/what-is-the-integral-of-function-fx-sin-x-x

This link should help you with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$\color{#00f}{\large{\rm Si}\left(\pi\right)}$$

> $\displaystyle{\rm Si}\left(x\right)$ is the
>   [Sine Integral Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral).

Answer (score 1):

Beside the answers given in other post, you could develop $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as a Taylor series built around $x=0$ and integrate. For example, if you use $20$ terms, you would arrive to  $1.851937051982916663426668$; $30$ terms would give $1.851937051982466170360965$; $40$  terms would give $1.851937051982466170361053$.

Answer (score -2):

Your number is sometimes called [the Gibbs constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wilbraham-GibbsConstant.html) and evaluates to

```
1.85193705198246617036105337015799136334580972898115
  49098047837818769818901663483585327103365029547577
```

with 100 digit accuracy. It is most likely not expressible in a simple way in terms of other "well-known" constants.