# How to prove $\operatorname{si}(0) = -\pi/2$ without contour

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \ dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2)

How to prove $\operatorname{si}(0) = -\pi/2$ without contour integration ?
Where $\operatorname{si}(x)$ is the [sine integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral).

Comment: Isn't $\operatorname{Si}(0)=\int_0^0\frac{\sin x}{x}\ dx=0$?

Comment: Well if you're talking about $$\text{Si}(z):=\int_0^z\frac{\sin t}t\,dt,$$ then $\text{Si}(0)=0$. Did you mean something else, perhaps?

Comment: I think you mean $Si(\infty)$ or $-si(0)$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_integral#Sine_integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**:

Note that our integral may be rewritten as 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy} \sin x \ dy \ dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \ dx$$
but integrating with respect to x we get that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy} \sin x \ dx \ dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^2} \ dy$$
Hence I hope you can handle it on your own.