# Evaluation of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(at)}t\ dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, change-of-variable

I just need to know if this integral converges.  If it does, what is the value?

If not can anyone tell me what is the value of the $$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2\,\frac{\cos(w)\sin(w)}{w}\ dw ? $$

Comment: Check out the [Dirichlet integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral).

Answer (score 3):

The improper integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(at)}{t}\,dt$$
converges. Indeed, consider
$$\int_{c}^{d}\frac{\sin(at)}{t}\,dt$$
If we substitue $x=at$, $dx=adt$,
$$\int_{c}^{d}\frac{\sin(at)}{t}\,dt=\int_{ac}^{ad}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$$
If $a>0$, as $c\to -\infty$ and $d\to +\infty$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(at)}{t}\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\pi$$
I will leave the cases $a=0$, $a<0$ to the OP.
We also have that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2\,\frac{\cos(w)\sin(w)}{w}\ dw= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(2w)}{w}\ dw=...$$

Answer (score 1):

In light of @Sasha's comment, $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ converges. Since $\int_0^{1}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ converges (because $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is continous in $(0,1]$ and its limit is equal to $1$ when $x\to 0^+$) wee need just to show that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ converges. Doing the integration by parts, so we have $$\int_1^{a}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{-\cos x}{x}\big|_1^a+\int_1^{a}\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx=\cos1-\frac{\cos a}{a}+\int_1^{a}\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx$$ Now by taking the limit of both sides when $a\to \infty$ and the fact that $\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{\cos a}{a}=0$ we have $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\cos1+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx$$ But the last interal on the RHS converges(why?).

Answer (score -1):

Setting $u= at$ then , since the integrand is an odd function 
we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(at)}{t}\,dt = 2sign(a)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(at)}{t}\,dt=2sign(a)\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt= sign(a)\pi $$

See here, for the convergence, 
[Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \ dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2)

Comment: why did somebody down vote this ?