# Showing that $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

How can I show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx$ converges?

I have that $\sin(x)\leq x$ for $x\geq 0$ so then $\sin(1/x)\leq 1/x$ for $x\geq 0$. It follows then that $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx \leq \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\ dx = 1$ so it doesn't diverge to $\infty$. I think it's also easy to show that it doesn't diverge in the oscillatory sense because of the dampening.

But how does one go about showing that $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx$ converges?

I'm studying for an analysis exam so anything else that someone might want to mention in that sort of thing would be appreciated.

Comment: intuitively : note that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} dx$ diverges, but not much is needed for it to converge. in particular, it diverges exactly in the same way that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx$, and you have to remember that $\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$ converges whenever $f(x)$ is periodic and zero-mean. in fact even $\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^\epsilon} dx$ converges (it reduces to an alternated series !). finally, you'll have to see why $\int_0^1 \frac{f(1/x)}{x} dx$ is exactly the same, and hence $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}dx$ converges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But how does one go about showing that $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx$ converges?*

One may observe that, by the change of variable $\displaystyle u=\frac1x$,
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin u}u\:du.
$$
Then one may perform an integration by parts,
$$
\int_1^M\frac{\sin u}u\:du=\left.\frac{-\cos u}u\right|_1^M-\int_1^M\frac{\cos u}{u^2}\:du
$$ and the latter integral is absolutely convergent:
$$
\left|\int_1^M\frac{\cos u}{u^2}\:du\right|\leq \int_1^M\frac1{u^2}\:du<\infty
$$ giving the convergence of $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty\frac{\sin u}u\:du$ thus the convergence of $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx$.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a $u$-substitution with $u=\dfrac{1}{x} \quad du=-\dfrac{1}{x^2}dx=-u^2dx$

$\int_\infty^0 \sin(u)\cdot \dfrac{u}{-u^2}du=\int^\infty_0\dfrac{\sin u}{u}du$

While this is sufficient to show that the integral converges since $\sin(u)$ is bounded while $u$ is not, it is also interesting to show that the integral is precisely $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

You can read more about the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Answer (score 0):

For $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}dx,$ you really need absolute values. We actually have $|\sin u|\leq u$ for $u\geq 0$. Now, you may estimate as you have done to show that piece is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick: If we set $ x=\frac{1}{2u}$ that is $\frac{1}{x} =2u$  then, $dx = -\frac{1}{2u^2}du$ and Given that $\lim_{u\to  \infty}\frac{ \sin^2 u}{u} = \lim_{u\to  0}\frac{ \sin^2 u}{u} =0$ we get

\begin{split}
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx &=& \int_0^{+\infty} 2u \sin(2u) \left(\frac{1}{2u^2}du\right)= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(2u)}{u} \ du\\&=&
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{2\cos u\sin u}{u} \ du=
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(\sin^2 u)'}{u} \ du~~~~\text{since}~~~~(\sin^2 u)' =2\cos u\sin u\\&=&
\left[\frac{ \sin^2 u}{u} \right]_0^\infty+\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ \sin^2 u}{u^2} \ du~~~\text{by integration by part}~\\&=&\color{blue}{\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ \sin^2 u}{u^2}du=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ \sin u}{u}du =\frac{π}{2 }}
\end{split}

you Can get the last line from the first line  or [see this post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508827)  and use the following:[Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \ dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2)

**Proof of the convergence** However, For $u>1$ $$\frac{\sin^2u}{u^2}\le \frac{1}{u^2} \implies \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{ \sin^2 u}{u^2}du \le \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ 1}{u^2}du$$ and  For $u<1$ 
$$ |\sin u|\le |u|\implies \frac{\sin^2 u}{u^2}\le  1 \implies \int_0^{1} \frac{ \sin^2 u}{u^2}du\le 1.$$

Thus, 
\begin{split}
\color{red}{\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\ dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ \sin^2 u}{u^2}du<\infty}
\end{split}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\left(\frac{\sin(\pi(x+2k))}{\pi(x+2k)}+\frac{\sin(\pi(x+2k+1))}{\pi(x+2k+1)}\right)\mathrm{d}\pi x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x+2k}-\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x+2k+1}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(x+2k)(x+2k+1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\pi\log(2)+\frac2\pi\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2k(2k+1)}\\
&=\pi\log(2)+\frac2\pi(1-\log(2))
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The actual value of the integral is $\frac\pi2$, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/594681) or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1278017) using contour integration.