# Integrating $\sin(x)/x$, how to treat the pole at the origin?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I want to use residue theory to integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$

What would be a good contour to use?

I plan to take the imaginary part of this integral:

$$\int \frac {e^{iz}}{z} dz$$

The integrand has a simple pole at the origin, so that is a bit problematic.

So, I thought of choosing an upper semicircular contour, with a small semicircular indent going over the origin.

The estimate over the big semicircle is easy to give and the integral on it goes to zero, as the radius $R$ grows to infinity.

The integration over the two half lines are the desired integrals.  And the integration should be set equal to **zero**, since this choice of contour avoids the pole at the origin, and by Cauchy's Theorem, the integration of an analytic function over a closed contour is just zero.

Now the only trouble is evaluating the integral over the small semicircular indent, call it $C_{\epsilon}$.

Parametrizing, we have that $z= \epsilon e^{i\theta}$ for $\pi \ge \theta \ge 0$.

Then the contour integral is (after a bit of simplification):

$$\int_{\pi}^0  e^{\large i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}i d\theta$$

$$=-i\int_0^{\pi}  e^{\large i\epsilon e^{i\theta}} d\theta$$

I'm not sure how to evaluate this integral, so any hints or comments are welcome.

Also, if you think a completely different approach would be better, please feel free to comment.

Thanks,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594641/computing-int-infty-infty-frac-sin-xx-mathrmdx-with-residue-calc

Comment: Remember that you will take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$.  It is easy to justify interchanging the limit with the integral.  Inasmuch as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}e^{i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}=1$, the resulting integral over the semicircle is $-i \pi$.  Thus, the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral of interest is $\pi$ (after taking the imaginary part).

Comment: @angryavian: I was just about to post a link to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/594681), but you beat me with a link to the corresponding question.

Comment: Thanks for the link at @angryavian.

Comment: Thanks so much @Dr.MV.  I think that I was able to justify it.  The upper bound for the integrand was $e^{\large -\epsilon sin(\theta)}$, which is continuous over $[0,\pi]$, hence integrable over $[0,\pi]$, and so the dominated convergence theorem is applicable here.

Comment: Although Daniel Fischer claims (on the link mentioned by robjohn) that in fact I can use a weaker assumption and show the *uniform* convergence of $\large e^{i \epsilon e^{i\theta}} \to 1$, in order to justify swapping the limit with the integral, but I am having some trouble with specifying a suitable $\epsilon_0$ so that for any $\delta >0$, whenever $\epsilon < \epsilon_0$, we have that $|\large e^{i \epsilon e^{i\theta}} - 1| < \delta$.  What do you think would be a good choice?  Thanks, @Dr. MV

Comment: Thanks as usual, @robjohn :-)

Comment: @User001: Since $\left|\,ie^{i\theta}\,\right|=1$ and $\left|\,e^z-1\,\right|=\left|\,\int_0^1e^{tz}z\,\mathrm{d}t\,\right|\le\left| z\,\right|e^{\left|z\right|}$ we have $$\left|\,e^{\large i\epsilon e^{i\theta}}-1\right|\le\epsilon e^\epsilon$$ Does that help?

Comment: One doesn't select $\epsilon$; one must find for any $\epsilon$ a $\delta$.  @Robjohn has provided a way forward for you. ;-))  - Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\gamma_r$ is the small upper half circle with radius of $r<1$ bypassing $0$. Then
$$
\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz=\int_{\gamma_r}\left(\frac1{z}+g(z)\right)dz\tag1
$$
where 
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^nz^{n-1}}{n!}
$$
and is analytic for $|z|<1$. Since $|g(z)|<M$ for $|z|<1$
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma_r}g(z)dz\right|<\pi Mr\to0
$$
as $r\to0$. So
$$
\lim_{r\to0}\int_{\gamma_r}g(z)dz=0
$$
Thus by $(1)$
$$
\lim_{r\to0}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz=\lim_{r\to0}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac1{z}dz=\lim_{r\to0}\int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{ire^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}}d\theta=-\pi i
$$

Comment: Thanks so much @hermes :-)