# Integral $e^{iz}/z$ over upper semi-circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is to compute $\int_{\gamma}e^{iz}/z$ for $\gamma:[0,\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\gamma(t)=re^{it}$ with $r>0$.

I tried to make it a closed arc, say add two segments in real line connecting $-r$ and $-\epsilon$, $\epsilon$ and $r$, then connect $-\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ by an upper semi circle. So the integral over this contour is 0. But it turns out that $\int_{-r}^{-\epsilon}+\int_{\epsilon}^r \frac{e^{it}}{t} dt$ is not computable? Is there any other way to compute it?

Comment: You have to use residues I believe. Maybe this helps? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594641/computing-int-infty-infty-frac-sin-xx-mathrmdx-with-residue-calc

Comment: Are you familiar with the [sine-integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) function, $\mathrm{Si}(r)$?

Comment: I only know little about it.