# $x\rightarrow \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\operatorname{sin}(t)}{t}$ is a bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I've already proved that the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{sin}(t)}{t}$ is convergent.

I don't know its limit though...

> I'm asked to prove that 
>   $\begin{array}{ccccc}
> f & : & \mathbb R & \to & \mathbb R \\
>  & & x & \mapsto & \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\operatorname{sin}(t)}{t} \\
> \end{array}$
>
> is a bounded function.

I don't know how to proceed. We're not looking for what happens at $\infty$ so my reasoning for the convergence of the integral yields nothing.

What approach is suitable here?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2/8350#8350

Comment: Tu as supprimé ta question ?

Comment: @Julien elle n'avait aucun sens en fait (formulée comme telle). En fait je cherchais le min de la fonction $x \rightarrow \frac{1}{ |1-e^{inx}|}$ à $n$ fixé.

Comment: Ah, d'accord..$$ $$ $$

Comment: @Julien t'as une idée du minimum ?

Comment: Le minimum sur $\mathbb{R}$ ? Tu peux déjà utiliser le théorème fondamentale pour montrer que ça tend vers $0$ à n fixé.

Comment: @Julien non... c'est faux

Comment: Oui tu as raison, cela dit $\left|1 - e^{inx}\right|=2\left|\sin\frac{nx}{2}\right|$, là tu devrais pouvoir conclure ;)

Comment: @Julien merci ! Bientôt les concours pour toi aussi ?

Comment: Oui bientôt, la tension monte.. Tu passes tout les concours ?

Comment: Non juste X/centrales/mines... Et toi?

Comment: Moi pas l'X car je suis candidat libre donc j'ai pas de point de bonif, donc Centrale et Mines simplement. Tu vises l'X? J'espère que tu l'auras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt \stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=} \left[\frac{1-\cos t}{t}\right]_{0}^{x}+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}\,dt $$
and since $0\leq 1-\cos t\leq \min(1,t^2)$ we have
$$ 0 \leq \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt \leq \min\left(x,\frac{1}{x}\right)+2\leq 3 $$
for any $x>0$. The stationary points of $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$ occur at $\pi,2\pi,3\pi,\ldots$, so we may easily improve such bound:
$$ \forall x>0,\qquad 0\leq \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt \leq 1.851937\ldots = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt. $$
$f(x)$ is an odd function, so $|f(x)|<\frac{13}{7}$ holds over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why people voted for closing...

Anyway,  the answer to this question is actually very simple: the function considered here is continuous,  has limits at both $0$ and $\infty$ and is therefore bounded.