# Trigonometric functions expressed as definite integrals with Bessel functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, bessel-functions

Prove that 
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}J_0(x\cos(\theta))\cos(\theta)\,d\theta \tag{a}$$
$$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}J_1(x\cos(\theta))\,d\theta  \tag{b}$$
 Hint:
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^{2s+1}(\theta)\,d\theta  = \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot6\cdots(2s)}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2s+1)}$$

I have no  idea how to approach this problem.  Any suggestions?  I did express sine function in exponential form but then I have no clue where to go from  there so that I can end up with the integral as an answer indicated above.

Comment: I gave you the answer and it is the first answer to be posted. I want you to do the details if you want to learn.

Comment: ... except that I already gave all the details in the answer of mine :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The main thing in solving problems is idea! The details are left for the OP's. So Let me deal with the OP instead of jumping and working on my ideas and hints.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: you are free to do what you want, but I think that to take the exclusive right to use power series and to state that I "jumped on your ideas" is a bit too much. Bury the hatchet, please.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: You can come up with your idea and work the details out!

Comment: I can't stand: I have already written a solution. I see no reason to avoid the use of power series just because you have suggested to use power series. I am free to use them just as you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$J_0(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{4^m\,m!^2}x^{2m}\tag{1}$$
we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_0(x\cos\theta)\cos\theta\,d\theta&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m x^{2m}}{4^m\,m!^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cos\theta)^{2m+1}d\theta\\&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m x^{2m}}{4^m\,m!^2}\cdot\frac{4^m\,m!^2}{(2m+1)!}\\&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m x^{2m}}{(2m+1)!}=\frac{\sin x}{x}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
In a similar way
$$ J_1(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{2\cdot 4^m\, (m+1)\,m!^2}x^{2m+1}\tag{2}$$
gives:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_1(x\cos\theta)\,d\theta&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m\,x^{2m+1}}{2\cdot 4^m\, (m+1)\,m!^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cos\theta)^{2m+1}d\theta\\&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m\,x^{2m+1}}{2\cdot 4^m\, (m+1)\,m!^2}\cdot\frac{4^m\,m!^2}{(2m+1)!}\\&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m x^{2m+1}}{(2m+2)!}=\frac{1-\cos x}{x}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ can be derived from the integral representations given in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for Bessel functions.

Comment: I already gave him the hint or you are using some thing different.

Comment: I just wrote down all the steps.

Comment: The whole idea is to teach people here. So that's why we give the main idea which is the key to solve the problem and let the OP to do the details. Me myself I know how do these details but the as I said it is not of the benefit of the OP. Thanks for doing this.

Comment: I know, but I thought that an answer like "Use power series. And the identity it was given." would be quite useless for teaching purposes. Sometimes details matter - just my two cents, obviously.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am having difficulty deriving (1) and (2). I have gone through the Wikipedia page and my textbook and attempted to derive these on my own but cannot seem to get them. Can you direct me on how you got these please?

Answer (score 1):

The first integral is the case $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ of the integral formula

$$\frac{2^{1/2-\alpha} \, \Gamma(1- \alpha)}{\sqrt{\pi}} \, \sin(x) \, x^{\alpha-3/2} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} J_{\alpha-1/2}(x \cos \theta) \cos^{\alpha+1/2}(\theta) \sin^{1- 2 \alpha}(\theta) \, \mathrm d \theta, \tag{1}$$

where $x>0$ and $0 < \alpha <1$.

I stumbled upon $(1)$ while messing around with the [Abel transform](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelTransform.html).  (It can, of course, be proven in a more direct manner using the beta function.)

A variant of the Abel transform states that if  $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{g(t)}{(x^{2}-t^{2})^{\alpha}} \, \mathrm dt, \quad 0 < \alpha <1, $$

then $$g(t) = \frac{2 \sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{x f(x)}{(t^{2}-x^{2})^{1- \alpha}}  \, \mathrm dx.$$

I'll post a proof at the end.

If we let $f(x) = \sin(x)$, then $$g(t) = \frac{2 \sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{x \sin (x)}{(t^{2}-x^{2})^{1 - \alpha}} \, \mathrm dx.  $$

Integrating by parts and using [Poisson's integral representation of the Bessel function of the first kind](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E4), we get $$ \begin{align} g(t) &= \frac{\sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi \alpha } \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \int_{0}^{t} (t^{2}-x^{2})^{\alpha} \cos(x) \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{\sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi \alpha } \left( (t^{2}-t^{2})^{\alpha} \cos(t) + 2t \alpha\int_{0}^{t} (t^{2}-x^{2})^{\alpha -1} \cos(x)  \, \mathrm dx  \right) \\ &=  \frac{2 t \sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \int_{0}^{t} (t^{2}-x^{2})^{\alpha -1} \cos(x)  \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{2 t \sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \int_{0}^{t}  t^{2(\alpha -1)} \left(1- \left(\frac{x}{t}\right)^{2} \right)^{\alpha-1} \cos(x) \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \frac{2t^{2 \alpha} \sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \int_{0}^{1} (1-u^{2})^{\alpha -1} \cos(tu) \, \mathrm du \\ &=  \frac{2t^{2 \alpha} \sin(\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \, \Gamma(\alpha)}{2 \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^{\alpha -1/2}} \, J_{\alpha - 1/2}(t) \\&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \, 2^{1/2-\alpha}  \, t^{\alpha+1/2}}{\Gamma(1-a)}  \, J_{\alpha-1/2}(t)  . \end{align} $$

Therefore,  $$\begin{align} \sin(x)  &= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{g(t)}{(x^{2}-t^{2})^{\alpha}} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{x^{2 \alpha}} \frac{g(t)}{\left(1- \left(\frac{t}{x} \right)^{2} \right)^{\alpha}} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= x^{1- 2 \alpha} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{g(xv)}{(1-v^{2})^{\alpha}} \, \mathrm dv \\ &= x^{1- 2 \alpha} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1-v^{2})^{\alpha}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \, 2^{\alpha-1/2}  \, (xv)^{\alpha+1/2}}{\Gamma(1-a)}  \, J_{\alpha-1/2}(xv) \, \mathrm dv \\ &= \frac{ \sqrt{\pi} \, 2^{\alpha-1/2} \,  x^{3/2- \alpha}  }{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{v^{\alpha +1/2}}{(1-v^{2})^{\alpha}} \, J_{\alpha-1/2}(xv) \, \mathrm dv \\ &= \frac{ \sqrt{\pi} \, 2^{\alpha-1/2} \, x^{3/2- \alpha}}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}  \int_{0}^{\pi/2 } J_{\alpha-1/2}(x \cos \theta) \cos^{\alpha+1/2}(\theta) \sin^{1- 2 \alpha}(\theta) \, \mathrm d \theta. \end{align}$$

---

**Proof of the Abel transform**:

Assume that $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{g(t)}{(x^{2}-t^{2})^{\alpha}} \, \mathrm dt, \quad 0 < \alpha < 1. $$

Then $$ \begin{align} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{x}{(t^{2}-x^{2})^{1- \alpha}} \, f(x) \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{0}^{t} \frac{x}{(t^{2}-x^{2})^{1- \alpha}} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{g(y)}{(x^{2}-y^{2})^{\alpha}} \, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{t} g(y) \int_{y}^{t} x (t^{2}-x^{2})^{\alpha-1} (x^{2}-y^{2})^{-\alpha}  \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} g(y) \int_{y^{2}}^{t^{2}} (t^{2}-u)^{\alpha-1} (u-y^{2})^{-\alpha} \, \mathrm du \, \mathrm dy \\ &\overset{(2)}{=} \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} g(y) \int_{0}^{1} (1-w)^{\alpha-1} w^{-\alpha} \, \mathrm dw \, \mathrm dy \\&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} g(y) \, B \left(1- \alpha, \alpha \right) \mathrm dy  \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \csc(\pi \alpha)  \int_{0}^{t} g(y) \, \mathrm dy. \end{align}$$

Now differentiate both sides of the above equation with respect to $t$.

---

$(2)$ Let $w = \frac{u-y^2}{t^2-y^2}$.