# Prove the relation $\frac{1}{x}$=$\int^\infty_0$ $e^{-xt}$ dt, for $x>0$. Use it to prove $\int^\infty_0$ $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ dx = $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Prove the relation $$\frac{1}{x} = \int^\infty_0 e^{-xt}\,  \text{d}t, \text{ for } x>0.$$
>
> Use it to prove $$\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\, \text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

"Hint: Use appropriate double integrals as in calculus. When the double integrals are proper, the conditions for switching the order of integration are valid. Then take the limits." I'm assuming that's for the second part but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hint: the derivative of $e^t$ is $e^t$. Can you evaluate the first integral now?

Comment: Yes the hint is for the second part and the first part should be easy!

Comment: For the second one integrate by parts two times, after using Fubini. Otherwise, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2) where Aryabhata already solved the [same exercise](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/5257/119527).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\sin (x)dtdx=\int_0^\infty\operatorname{Im}\int_0^\infty e^{x(i-t)}dxdt\\=\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+t^2}dt=\arctan t\Bigg|_0^{\infty}=\frac\pi2$$

Comment: I hope they give you credit on their homework. Of course, I bet that complex functions have not been covered yet.

Comment: I haven't the intention to do his homework, just I want to help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}dt=\left[-\frac{1}{x}e^{-xt}\right]_0^\infty =\frac{1}{x}-\underbrace{\lim_{t\to\infty }\frac{1}{x}e^{-xt}}_{=0}=\frac{1}{x}$$