# uniform bound for sine integral function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, improper-integrals, special-functions

Prove that for any $0<a<b$,
$$
\left|\int_a^b\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\right|\le4
$$
Here is my approach. I used integration by parts to prove that LHS is bounded by $3$ when $a\ge 1$. I will be done if I can show LHS is $\le1$ when $b=1$. I do not know if this is true or not.

Comment: [You can find usefull this answering][1]
Remember that $\frac{sinx}{x}$ is an odd function.

  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2

Comment: @DavideMarano Here $a>0$. So the fact the integrand is odd is not helpful.

Comment: Can we have the same bound for $a < 0$ as well?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Prove that the integral achieves its maximum value when $a = -\pi$, $b = \pi$. Then just complete the proof for that case.

Comment: Did you mean $a=0, b=\pi$? The function is odd.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but anyway. As for the question for the LHS being $\leq 1$ when $b =1 $, I think one can prove directly that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\frac{\sin x}{x}dx \leq 1. \quad(*)
\end{equation} 
Integrating by parts
$$\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = -\sin\epsilon\ln\epsilon - \int^1_\epsilon\ln x\cos x dx.$$
Then use that
$$- \int^1_\epsilon\ln x\cos x dx \leq - \int^1_\epsilon\ln xdx,$$
because $-\ln x\cos x\leq -\ln x$ for $\epsilon < x < 1$ and evaluate the integral to obtain
$$\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\sin x}{x}dx \leq -\sin\epsilon\ln\epsilon + 1 - \epsilon + \epsilon\ln\epsilon.$$
Finally, take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ (L'Hôpital, for example) to get $(*)$.