# Prove $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x} dx}{x} $ converges.

Tags: calculus, analysis

The fact that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x} dx}{x} $ converges has been proven multiple times for example: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2?lq=1)

However I am wondering what is the way of proving it using Cauchy-Bolzano criterion.

Comment: If you only want to know that the integral converges, you can break $(0,\infty)$ into $(0,\pi/2)$, $(\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$..... and argue similarly as in alternating series test for series,

Comment: @John: In my opinion, the easiest way to prove convergence is to integrate by parts: this leads to the integral $\int \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx$ which converges absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The criterion would be: for every $\epsilon$, there exists $T$ such that for every $U > T$, we have $\big|\int_T^U \frac{\sin x}x\,dx\big| < \epsilon$. This can be proved by integrating by parts:
\begin{align*}
\bigg| \int_T^U \frac{\sin x}x\,dx \bigg| &= \bigg| {-}\frac{\cos x}x \bigg|_T^U - \int_T^U \frac{\cos x}{x^2}\,dx \bigg| \\
&\le \frac1T + \frac1U + \int_T^U \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx < \frac3T.
\end{align*}
So choosing $T = \frac3\epsilon$ suffices.