# Fourier transform of the 2D Coulomb potential

Tags: fourier-transform

To begin with, it's known that
$$V(q)=\int d^{2} r e^{-i q \cdot r} \frac{1}{r}=\frac{2\pi}{q}$$
but I would like to understand as much of this calculation as possible.

We can begin calculating the Fourier transform of the 2D Coulomb potential with
$$V(q)=\int d^{2} r e^{-i q \cdot r} \frac{1}{r}=\int_{0}^{\infty} r d r \int_{0}^{2 \pi} d \theta e^{-i q r \cos \theta} \frac{1}{r}=\int_{0}^{\infty} d r \int_{0}^{2 \pi} d \theta e^{-i q r \cos \theta}$$
Then we can use one of Bessel's integrals
$$2 \pi J_{0}(x)=\int_{0}^{2 \pi} d \theta e^{-i x \cos \theta}$$
to obtain
$$V(q)=\int_{0}^{\infty} d r \int_{0}^{2 \pi} d \theta e^{-i q r \cos \theta}=2 \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} d r J_{0}(q r)=\frac{2 \pi}{q} \int_{0}^{\infty} q d r J_{0}(q r)=\frac{2 \pi}{q} \int_{0}^{\infty} d u J_{0}(u)$$
Apparently the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} d u J_{0}(u)=1$$
but I have not found a proof of this.

Where can I find a proof of this? I have found proofs of Bessel's integrals but not this definite integral.

Comment: This is essentially a math question, and should probably be migrated to the maths site.

Comment: Have you tried looking for references? Gradstein & Ryzhik is well indexed and suitably referenced (say, to specific points in Watson or the Bateman Manuscript Project) to places that sometimes (though then again not always) present proofs.

Comment: In that line, your integral is 6.511.1 in G&R, and it's referenced to "ET II 22(3)", which means Erdelyi et al., Tables of Integral Transforms, vol. II, p. 22, eq 3. Unfortunately, that's unlikely to provide a proof. Maybe Watson has one?

Comment: The physicist's way of doing it is to include a regulator to deal with the problem at $r=0$, and then take the regulator to zero at the end of the calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the Laplace transform  of the Bessel function, which is given by (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485317/laplace-transform-of-the-zeroth-order-bessel-function))
$$
L[J_0(z)] = \int_0^\infty J_0(z) e^{-st}dz 
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2 +1}}
$$
Now insert $s=0$. Viola.