# Inverse Fourier transform of the 2D Yukawa potential

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I am trying to understand how to do the inverse Fourier transform for the Coulomb/Yukawa potential in 2D. So $$V(r) = \frac{e^2}{r}e^{-\lambda r}.$$ The Fourier transform says $$V(q) = \frac{2\pi e^2}{\sqrt{q^2+\lambda^2}}.$$

I learned how to do this from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3627267/fourier-transform-of-the-2d-coulomb-potential). I also understand how to go back in the case when $\lambda = 0$. But for positive $\lambda$, I run into $$f(\lambda) = \int_0^{\infty}dq J_0(q)\frac{q}{\sqrt{q^2+\lambda^2}}.$$
From the Fourier transform I know $f(\lambda) = \exp(-\lambda)$. But I am not sure how to get there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to derive Hankel transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+a^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470012/how-to-derive-hankel-transform-of-frac1-sqrtr2a2). For comparison, note that your integral can be read off as $F_0(k=1)$ for the order-$0$ Hankel transform of $1/\sqrt{q^2+\lambda^2}$ with respect to $q$.

Comment: @Semiclassical It does, thank you!