# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to prove that

> $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x} dx$$

is convergent;

I know that $\int \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}=\frac{1-\cos(\pi x)}{\pi x}+ \int \frac{1-\cos(\pi x)}{\pi x^2} dx$.

Comment: First consider $\int_0^R$. Try splitting integral as $\int_0^1 + \int_1^2 + \cdots +\int_{\lfloor R \rfloor}^R$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $\sin(\pi x)$ has a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing towards zero as $x\to +\infty$, hence the integral is convergent by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) (integral version).

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2/1847675#1847675) deals with the computation of that integral.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Integrating by parts as you did is Ok, one has for $M>0$,
$$
\int_{0}^M \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x} dx=\left.\frac{1-\cos(\pi x)}{\pi x}\right]_0^M+ \int_0^M \frac{1-\cos(\pi x)}{\pi x^2} dx
$$ then letting $M \to \infty$ gives
$$
\left|\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x} dx\right|=\left|\lim_{M \to \infty}\int_{0}^M \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x} dx\right|\le \int_0^1 \left|\frac{1-\cos(\pi x)}{\pi x^2}\right| dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{|2|}{\pi x^2} dx<\infty
$$

Comment: Estimate $|1-\cos(\pi x)|$ from above by $2$, not $1$.

Comment: @GEdgar You are right! Thank you very much!