# Prove that $\int\limits_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> Prove the convergence of
>
> $$\int\limits_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

First I thought the integral does not converge because

$$\int\limits_1^{\infty} -\frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x \le \int\limits_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x}  \, \mathrm{d}x$$

But in this case

$$\int\limits_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \le \int\limits_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2}  \, \mathrm{d}x$$

it converges concerning the majorant criterion. What's the right way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: If you want to use the (direct) comparison test(s), be sure to check if you can apply the test (more specifically, look for conditions on the sign of the functions).

Comment: $f,g:[0,\infty]\to \mathbb{R}$, is this the problem?

Comment: @jacmeird The problem is that $\frac{\cos x}{x}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}$  is not true! Take any $x>1$ such that $\cos x = 1$ and you will see.

Comment: @5xum Ouch, of course you're right. If I take $\frac{cos(x)}{x} \le \frac{1}{x}$, there is the same problem.

Comment: You can apply most, if not all, of the same techniques found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use integration by parts, obtaining for $M\ge1$,
$$
\int_{1}^M \frac{\cos x}{x}\: dx=\left[\frac{\sin x}{ x}\right]_1^M+ \int_1^M \frac{\sin x}{x^2}\: dx
$$ letting $M \to \infty$ gives
$$
\int_{1}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x} \:dx=\lim_{M \to \infty}\int_1^M \frac{\cos x}{x}  \:dx= -\sin 1+\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{ x^2}\: dx
$$then one may conclude by the absolute convergence of the latter integral:
$$
\left|\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin x}{ x^2}\: dx\right|<\int_1^\infty \frac{|\sin x|}{ x^2}\: dx<\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\: dx<\infty.
$$

Comment: Is it $\left|\lim_{M \to \infty}\int_{1}^M \frac{\cos x}{x}  dx\right|$ ?

Comment: @McCheng Edited. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should leave off those absolute values in your last line.

Comment: @zhw. You are right, done.

Comment: I think you lost a minus sign in front of $\frac{\sin 1}{1}$, right?

Comment: @Ixion You are right, please feel free to edit my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

***Hint***: Awful and tricky but as the problem is near $+\infty$, write $$\int \limits_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{N\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x= \sum \limits_{k=1}^{N}\left(\int\limits_{k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x\right)$$ and use the criterion for alternating series with the sequence $$a_k=\int\limits_{k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|
&\le\left|\,\int_1^\pi\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\,\int_{(2k-1)\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\\
&=\left|\,\int_1^\pi\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\,\int_{(2k-1)\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi}\cos(x)\left(\frac1{x}-\frac1{2k\pi}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\\
&\le\log(\pi)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty2\pi\left(\frac1{(2k-1)\pi}-\frac1{2k\pi}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\log(4\pi)
\end{align}
$$