# Is this an invalid way to compute $\int_{2\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

So by using tabular integration:
$$\int_{2\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx$$ $$= \left. -\frac{1}{x}\cos(x) - \frac{1}{x^2}\sin(x) + \frac{2}{x^3}\cos(x) + \frac{2\cdot3}{x^4}\sin(x) - \frac{2\cdot3\cdot4}{x^5}\cos(x) - \frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5}{x^6}\sin(x) + \cdots \right|_{2\pi}^\infty$$

adding all the cosine terms gives:

$$\left.-\frac{1}{x}\cos(x)+ \frac{2}{x^3}\cos(x)- \frac{2\cdot3\cdot4}{x^5} \cos(x) + \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n-2)!}{x^{2n-1}} \cos(x) \right|_{2\pi}^\infty$$

and similarly for the sine terms:

$$\left.-\frac{1}{x^2}\sin(x)+ \frac{2\cdot3}{x^4}\sin(x)- \frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5}{x^6}\sin(x)+\cdots =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cdot (2n-1)!}{x^{2n}} 
\sin(x) \right|_{2\pi}^\infty$$

So putting everything back together we have:

$$\left.\int_{2\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n-2)!}{x^{2n-1}} \cos(x)+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n-1)!}{x^{2n}} \sin(x) \right|_{2\pi}^\infty$$

I think that as $x$ approaches $\infty$ the fractions in both sums approach $0$, so the top limit does not yield anything from the sums. Likewise, $\sin(2\pi) = 0$ and $\cos(2\pi) = 1$, so all that we are left with is:

$$\int_{2\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n (2n-2)!}{(2\pi)^{2n-1}}$$

However, putting this sum into wolfram I get that the sum is divergent, which doesn't seem right to me since $ f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ decreases to $0$ quite fast.

Is my logic inconsistent here? Have I done the integration incorrectly, or used a technique improperly/ inappropriately?

Comment: I have very little doubt that this integral converges, to about $0.1526...$.

Comment: I think you need to be more careful about plugging in $\infty$. It's not clear to me that that part vanishes since for any positive $x$, those sums do not converge.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Oh I see what you are saying, even though the fraction within the sum goes to 0, that doesn't mean that the sum itself will go to 0 as x approaches $\infty$.

Comment: I've done a little testing with wolfram alpha, and I've found that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, which would be very difficult to see from this sum. So, long story short, this is probably not an appropriate way to evaluate this integral it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{2\pi}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}\ &\ =\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\pi \over 2}}\ -\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{\mrm{Si}\pars{2\pi}}}\ =\
\color{#f00}{{\pi \over 2} - \mrm{Si}\pars{2\pi}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\mrm{Si}}$ is the
>   [Sine Integral Function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2.E9).

The $\,\mrm{Si}\pars{z}$ *series expansion* [is given by](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6.E5):
$$
\mrm{Si}\pars{z} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,
{z^{2n + 1} \over \pars{2n + 1}!\pars{2n + 1}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for this, I was not aware of this function until today! It seems I was steering way off course with my attempt. As an aside, I have also ran into this math exchange answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2

Comment: A small addendum: the given integral equals $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x+2\pi}\,dx$ that by exploiting the Laplace transform can be written as $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{1+s^2}\,ds$, probably more suited form numerical approximations. In this form, for instance, it is trivial that the integral is positive but bounded by $\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. It's a nice point of view.

Comment: Im sorry, but i'm having trouble seeing how you can tell $\int_{0}^{\infty} frac{\e^{-2\pi s}}{1+s^2} ds$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{2\pi}$. Could you elaborate/explain?

Comment: sorry I meant : $\int_{2\pi}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{1+s^2} ds$, mathematics stack exchange won't let me edit my own comment for some reason.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I guess the $\texttt{@user373763}$ last $\underline{two}$ comments are related to your comment.

Comment: @user373763: simply, $$0\leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{1+s^2}\,ds < \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-2\pi s}\,ds = \frac{1}{2\pi}.$$

Comment: @FelixMarin: thank you for notifying me.