# How to study the convergence of $\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{2\cos(t)\sin(t)}{t}dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

By using Taylor series, I managed to see that the $t \rightarrow 0$, $\frac{2\cos(t)\sin(t)}{t} = 1 -\frac{4t^2}{6}$ whose integral converges. As for the case when $t \rightarrow \infty$, I don't know that to do. It equals to $\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\sin(2t)}{t}dt$. What can I do?

Comment: Not that it helps, but you can simplify slightly to $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u}\;du$ by taking $u=2t$. Do you know about convergence of this integral?

Comment: @MPW I have a feeling it doesn't converge, but can't show it.

Comment: Consider the tail of the integral from R to infinity and perform a partial integration where you differentiate the 1/t factor.

Comment: what is $$\sint(t)$$? or is this a typo?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Yes, it does converge. Try googling "sinc"

Answer (score 0):

$$\eqalign{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2t)}{t}\; dt &= 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{n\pi/2}^{(n+1)\pi/2} \frac{\sin(2t)}{t}\; dt \cr
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(2t) \left(\frac{1}{t+n\pi/2} - \frac{1}{t+(n+1)\pi/2}\right)\cr
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2\pi\;\sin(2t)}{n^2 \pi^2 + \ldots}}$$
Now estimate...

Answer (score 0):

$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{sin(2t)}{t}dt$.
exists if $\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{sin(2t)} {t}dt$ exists

exists if $(1)\lim_{a\to0}\int^{1}_{a}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt$ exists and  $(2)\lim_{a\to\infty}\int^{b}_{1}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt$ exists

$(1)$ on $[0;1], \sin(x)\leq x, \sin(x)/x\leq1$

$\int^{1}_{a}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt \leq \int^{1}_{a}dt$, so $\lim_{a\to0}\int^{1}_{a}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt$ exists

$(2)$ let $u_n = \int^{\pi(n+2)}_{\pi(n+1)}\frac{sin(2t)}{t}dt $

$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int^{b}_{1}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt$ exists if $\sum u_n$ converges.
$\sum u_n$ is an alternating series, so $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int^{b}_{1}\frac{sin(t)}{t}dt$ exists.