# How may be prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(\cosh x)\cos(\sinh x)\mathrm dx={\pi\over 2}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given this integral

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(\cosh x)\cos(\sinh x)\mathrm dx={\pi\over 2}\tag1$$

**My try:**

Recall $$2\sin(A)\cos(B)=\sin(A-B)+\sin(A+B)$$

$(1)$ becomes

$$\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos(\cosh x-\sinh x)+\sin(e^x)\mathrm dx\tag2$$

Recall $$\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x=1$$

$(2)$ becomes

$$\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(e^{-x})+\sin(e^x)\mathrm dx\tag3$$

**How may be prove $(1)?$**

Comment: You should have a $\sin{(A-B)}$ on the RHS of the equation above (2).

Comment: using @Chappers correction and substitutions $e^{\pm x}=y$ this should be simple enough to finish

Comment: you also missed a factor of $2$...#

Comment: btw. what went wrong the last week?!

Comment: @tired, I lost around 200 rep :0.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai me 100 reps...since i am only parcitipating (and especially answer questions) occasionally this was the work of one month :(((

Comment: I promised to buy back the reps. Today they only allowed me only three bounty

Comment: @Latte', It is ok. Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct prosthaphaeresis formula is
$$ 2\sin{A}\cos{B} = \sin{(A+B)}+\sin{(A-B)}. $$
This gives
$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\sin{(e^{-x})} + \sin{(e^{x})}) \, dx, $$
from the definitions of the hyperbolic functions,
$$ \cosh{x}+\sinh{x} = e^x, \qquad \cosh{x}-\sinh{x} = e^{-x}. $$
The integrand is an even function, so this is the same as
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin{(e^{x})} \, dx $$
by putting $y=-x$ in one of the terms. Now put $y=e^{x}$. The limits change to $0$ and $\infty$, and $dx=dy/y$, so the integral becomes
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} \, dy, $$
which can be done in [numerous ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5248/221811).