# Alternative approach to the computation of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}xdx$

Tags: integration

I am not able to obtain the value of:$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{x}dx ,$$

By changing the order of integration of: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xy}\sin(nx) dx dy.$$
And by using differentiation under the integral sign.

---

If you can suggest some other method then please tell me. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that you can obtain the value of $\int \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}$ using $\int\int e^{-xy}\sin(nx)$ ?

Comment: @Surb Notice that: $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-xy}\sin(nx)~dy=\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a different method, start by substituting $u=nx$. Now, we must consider different cases:

---

For $n>0$, we obtain:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}~dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}~du$$
And for $n<0$, we have:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}~dx=\int_{0}^{-\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}~du=-\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}~du=-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}~du$$
Where on the last step, we used the fact that $\dfrac{\sin(u)}{u}$ is an even function. The case where $n=0$ is extremely easy to do, since the integrand is just $0$.

---

Putting it all together, we have for all $n\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}~dx=\operatorname*{sgn}(n)\cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}~du$$
Where we have made use of the [Sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

---

One can then make use of the following question on MSE: [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \ dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2)

There are **many** different methods listed there **without using** the change of order in integration and differentiation under the integral sign.