# Need some help with an integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, real-numbers

I was reading on integration techniques and a came across an example that is shown quite a lot around the web.

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac {\sin(x)}{x}\,dx $$

I do know the answer must be $\frac {\pi}{2}$.

There are many ways to solve this but I am interested in differentiation under the integral sign. I am sorry but I am having trouble grasping the concept.

Could someone please go over this integral with me in a more elementary way (kind of step-by step)?

Thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: More specifically, [this answer by xpaul](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/328403/81360) explains how to solve the particular integral using differentiation under the integral sign

Comment: thank you all for the comments , i will check these out!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom unfortunately the answer you linked is not the best. Indeed it is not clear that it is correct as stated.

Comment: Indeed you'll find many proofs in the link posted by Kemono Chen. More precisely, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/5249/164983) in the link uses differentiation under the integral sign.