# integrate $F(x)$: NO complex analysis, NO multivariable calculus

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, elementary-functions

Suppose I have an elementary function $F(x)$ for which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(x) \, \text{d}x $ has an elementary value. Here 'elementary value' means anything generated by $0,1,+,-,\div,\times,\exp,\sin$.

Suppose, indeed, I can compute this value by means of complex contours or multivariable calculus — the latter being involved, say, in Feynman's trick or in the Fourier transform.

Can it be proved that I could have given a proof that the integral has that exact value, by 'single-variable methods' alone? That is to say, without differentiating or integrating anything with two real variables $x,y$? Will it suffice to work in the language of single-variable calculus?

I don't profess to know any model theory, so do help me to formulate the question more precisely.

I'm astounded to learn that for $F(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, there are such methods: [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \ dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2)

But a general result would be all the more fascinating.

Comment: My guess: to your "Can it be proved" question the answer is NO.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "compute". I don't see how the standard meanings of "computation" would apply here (unless you give a list of permissible transformations or something). It is also not clear what you mean by "elementary value". I don't think it matters at all what the value is (you can make it zero by subtracting an elementary function from $F$), no matter how you interpret the rest of the question.

Comment: sorry @tomasz I've now made some clarificatory edits. I didn't mean 'compute', but rather 'give a proof of that exact value'.

Comment: I was going to say that I didn't think the integral of the Gaussian over $\mathbb{R}$ could be calculated this way, but no, [here are eleven proofs that the result is $\sqrt{\pi}$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf).  At least three of them only rely on single-variable calculus.

Comment: @ChrisSanders: This is better. Still, I don't think the value matters at all. Suppose the value is $\alpha$ for some $\alpha$. Then replace $F$ with $G=F-\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot (-\alpha)/ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}$. Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty G=0$ and $G$ is elementary, and as soon as you prove that the integral evaluates to $0$, you know that the integral of $F$ evaluates to $\alpha$.