# Does the improper integral $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x^2}$ exist?

Tags: analysis

> Does the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x^2}$ exist?

I don't know how to use the comparison test, and I cannot find a proper comparison function.

Comment: HINT: Try $u = 1/x$

Answer (score 1):

By a change of variables $u=\frac1{x^2},\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac2{x^3}$:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin(1/x^2)}x=\frac12\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin u}u\,du$$
Thus the original integral converges, since $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u\,du=\frac\pi2$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5248/357390) for example). Indeed, its value is
$$\frac12\left(\frac\pi2-\operatorname{Si}(1)\right)=0.31235\dots$$
where $\rm{Si}$ is the sine integral.

Answer (score 1):

If you set $y = 1/x^2$ i.e. $x = y^{-1/2}$ then $dx = -\frac12y^{-3/2}dy$, so $dx/x = -\frac12 dy/y$, and the integral becomes
$$ -\frac12\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin (y)}ydy$$
the convergence of the original integral is the same question as the convergence of
$$ -\frac12\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_1^a \frac{\sin (y)}ydy$$
The answer is yes, the improper integral exists, one can follow the proofs in [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \,\mathrm dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-mathrm-dx-frac-pi), but you won't get as clean a result. This integral evaluates to  $-\frac12(\operatorname{Si}(1)-\frac{\pi}{2})$.