# How would I show the result below using contour integration?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, contour-integration

How would I show the result below using contour integration?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos bx - \cos ax}{x^2} dx = \pi (a-b)$$ where a>b>0 using contour integration. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea what contour to use?  (There's an obvious one.)

Comment: Consider the region of a semi-circle in the first two quadrants of infinitely large radius which avoids the singularity at (0,0) by cutting out a semi-circle of infinitesimally small radius centered at (0,0).  Once you draw the contour out and label the regions, use Cauchy's first theorem.  If you still struggle, refer to @metamorphy 's post or say what you're struggling with.

Comment: I see, so it is a Cauchy principal value problem effectively? Thanks for your help with that!

Answer (score 0):

See [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \,\mathrm dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-mathrm-dx-frac-pi) on performing contour integration to get $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}x=\frac\pi2$. Then

\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos bx - \cos ax}{x^2} dx
 \overset{IBP} =2\int_0^\infty \frac{a\sin ax - b\sin bx}x=\pi (a-b) 
\end{align}