# Proving that the limit of the integral of the following version of the topologist's sine curve exists, but that of the absolute value doesn't

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology, proof-writing, examples-counterexamples

Consider the following variation of topologist's sine curve:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

I want to show that

$$\lim_{c \to 0} \int_c^1 \frac{1}{x} \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx$$ exists, but

$$\lim_{c \to 0} \int_c^1 \left|\frac{1}{x} \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \, dx$$

does not exist.

I am not sure how this can be shown. For instance, I am not sure how to establish that the limit above exists without knowing what the limiting value is. My ideas so far are that I will need to take the substitution $u = \frac{1}{x}$. If I do this, I get

$$\lim_{c \to 0} \int_c^1 \frac{1}{x} \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx = \lim_{c \to 0} \int_{\frac{1}{c}}^1 \frac{-\sin u}{u}  \, du$$

and similarly

$$\lim_{c \to 0} \int_c^1 \left|\frac{1}{x} \cdot \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right| \, dx = \lim_{c \to 0} \int_{\frac{1}{c}}^1 \left|\frac{-\sin u}{u}  \, du\right|$$

How can I develop this idea further to show what I need to show? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a substitution:
$$
\lim_{c\to 0^+} \int_c^1 \frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx
$$
$$
\stackrel{z=1/x}{=}\lim_{r\to +\infty} \int_r^1 z\sin\left(z\right)(-z^{-2})\,dz
$$
$$
=\lim_{r\to +\infty} \int_1^r\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\,dz
$$This is improperly integrable, but not absolutely so. If we extend the range of integration to $[0,\infty)$, the result is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5248) to equal $\pi/2$; on the other hand, if we take the absolute value of the integrand, the result diverges (a nice exercise: try comparing it to the harmonic series by integrating over intervals of length $\pi$, maybe over $[\pi,\infty)$).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if hints should be reserved for comments. I'm new to this and wasn't sure I should post this as a comment. Hope it helps!

Hint: focus on the fact that the original integrand gives a well-defined limit while the absolute value of that integrand doesn't give a limit. More specifically, notice that while the absolute value of the integrand is certainly monotonically decreasing on your interval, you can bound it below by a harmonic series in this case. On the other hand, when you don't take the absolute value, you have a cyclic function which $\textit{alternates}$ sign. Try to use this along with the fact that the absolute value of the integranded is monotonically decreasing to prove the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

To finish off the other answers: to show that
$$ \lim_{r\to \infty} \int_1^r \frac{\sin z}{z} \, dz $$
exists, use integration by parts:
$$ \int_1^r \frac{\sin z}{z} \, dz = - \left[\frac{\cos z}{z}\right]_1^r - \int_1^r \frac{\cos z}{z^2} \, dz .$$
You know
$$ \left|\int_r^\infty \frac{\cos z}{z^2} \, dz \right| \le \int_r^\infty \frac{1}{z^2} \, dz = \frac1r \to 0. $$