# Deriving the value of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$ by way of Fourier transformation

Tags: improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform, riemann-integration

Recall that the Fourier transform on the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C})$ is defined by $$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) e^{-2\pi i \langle x \mid \xi \rangle} dx$$ where $dx$ denotes integration wrt. the Lebesgue measure. Now one can show, that the Fourier transform is an isometric automorphism on the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C})$ (with inverse $\check{f}(\xi) = \hat{f}(-\xi)$) and since the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C})$ we may extend the Fourier transform (by utilization of Cauchy sequences and completeness of $L^2$) to an isometric automorphism $$\mathfrak{F} \colon L^2(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C})$$ In particular one can verify, that if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{C})$, then $$\mathfrak{F}(f)(\xi) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) e^{-2\pi i \langle x \mid \xi \rangle} dx$$

In the case where $d = 1$ we set $L^p(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}) = L^p$ for $p \geq 1$ and we now consider a specific example: Look at the characteristic function $f = \chi_{[-1,1]}$ of the interval $[-1,1]$. Then clearly $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$, so by what we have referred to earlier we know that $$\mathfrak{F}{f}(\xi) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-2\pi i \xi x} dx = \frac{\sin(2\pi \xi)}{\pi \xi}$$
Many resources now claim, that it is justified to take the inverse Fourier transform of $\mathfrak{F}f$ in the sense that $$f(\xi) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{\pi x} e^{2 \pi i x \xi} dx$$ and upon setting $\xi = 0$ we obtain $$\pi = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} dy$$

However it is very well known, that $\mathfrak{F}f \notin L^1$ and that the Lebesgue integral over $\mathbb{R}$ of $\frac{\sin(y)}{y}$ doesn't exist.

> I guess as this result only makes sense for a Fourier transform wrt. the improper Riemann integral I would be curious for references, or even better for a write-up proof on here, as to why this is justified. I would also like to know if there is some connection between the (extended) inverse Fourier transform restricted to $\mathfrak{F}(L^1 \cap L^2)$ and the improper Riemann integral, i.e. is it always true, that $$\forall f \in \mathfrak{F}(L^1 \cap L^2) \colon \mathfrak{F}^{-1}(f)(\xi) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{2\pi i \xi x} dx$$ where the RHS is now to be understood as an improper Riemann integral.

Comment: Perhaps you can find the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5248/168433

Comment: @md2perpe Maybe I overlook something, but it seems like the one answer  in this linked question that is related with my question occurs to have exactly the same flaw I am trying to address.

Comment: Since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$ isn't defined as a Lebesgue integral or a proper Riemann integral, we need to define it in some (natural) way. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/328403/168433) it's implicitly defined through analytic continuation. In [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2915904/168433) I use another approach. What definition feels most natural for you?

Comment: @md2perpe In your answer how can you take the Fourier transform of $1/x$ via the Fourier integral? As $1/x \notin L^1 \cap L^2$ I have troubles seeing how this is justified. What definition of an integral are you using there?

Comment: @md2perpe I think the improper Riemann integral would seem the most natural to me, that is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx = \lim\limits_{a \to -\infty, b \to \infty} \int_a^b \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx$$

Comment: When I take the Fourier transform of $1/x$ it's actually done as a distribution, but I abuse notation and write it as an integral.

Comment: @md2perpe Oh I see. I don't have too much of a clue about distributions. But if you want to write up an answer in terms of this distributional approach, I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A solution using Fourier transforms of distributions**

The [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) used here is
$$
\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i\xi x} dx.
$$

First we notice that
$$
\mathcal{F}\{\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[-1,1]}(x) e^{-i\xi x} dx = 2\frac{\sin\xi}{\xi},
$$
where $\chi_{A}$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A$.
Here the integral is well-defined so we haven't yet needed distributions.

But we get problems if we want to do the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ using integrals. We can however treat $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as a distribution, and by the Fourier inversion theorem ([rule 105](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional)), which is also valid for distributions, the above result implies that
$$
\mathcal{F}\{2\frac{\sin x}{x}\} = 2\pi \, \chi_{[-1,1]}(-\xi)
$$

Thus, formally, abusing notation,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx
= \left. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} e^{-i\xi x} dx \right|_{\xi=0}
= \left. \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin x}{x} \} \right|_{\xi=0}
= \pi \, \chi_{[-1,1]}(0)
= \pi.
$$

There is a problem with the last step. The expression $\pi \, \chi_{[-1,1]}(\xi)$ is here not defined pointwise, but should be treated as a distribution. This can be fixed by introducing a smoothing factor:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} dx
:= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left. \mathcal{F}\{ e^{-\epsilon x^2} \frac{\sin x}{x} \} \right|_{\xi=0}
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left. \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \mathcal{F}\{ e^{-\epsilon x^2} \} * \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin x}{x} \} \right) \right|_{\xi=0}
$$
Here, $\mathcal{F}\{ e^{-\epsilon x^2} \}$ is a smooth function so the convolution $\mathcal{F}\{ e^{-\epsilon x^2} \} * \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin x}{x} \}$ is also a smooth function. Furthermore,
$$
\left. \frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \mathcal{F}\{ e^{-\epsilon x^2} \} * \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin x}{x} \} \right) \right|_{\xi=0} 
= \left. \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}\{ e^{-\epsilon x^2} \}(\xi-\eta) \, \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin x}{x} \}(\eta) \, d\eta \right|_{\xi=0} \\
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}\{ e^{-\epsilon x^2} \}(-\eta) \, \mathcal{F}\{ \frac{\sin x}{x} \}(\eta) \, d\eta 
= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}} e^{-\eta^2/(4\epsilon)} \, \pi\,\chi_{[-1,1]}(\eta) \, d\eta \\
= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\eta^2/(4\epsilon)} \, \chi_{[-1,1]}(\eta) \, d\eta 
= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}} \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-\eta^2/(4\epsilon)} \, d\eta 
= \{ \eta = 2\sqrt{\epsilon}\kappa \} \\
= \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}} \int_{-1/(2\sqrt{\epsilon})}^{1/(2\sqrt{\epsilon})} e^{-\kappa^2} \, 2\sqrt{\epsilon}\,d\kappa 
= \sqrt{\pi} \int_{-1/(2\sqrt{\epsilon})}^{1/(2\sqrt{\epsilon})} e^{-\kappa^2} \, \,d\kappa \\
\to \sqrt{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\kappa^2} \, \,d\kappa 
= \pi
.
$$