# $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\sin \frac{x}{3}}{\frac{x}{3}} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and more general results?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Problem: evaluate that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\sin \frac{x}{3}}{\frac{x}{3}} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and prove if a more general case, $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\sin \frac{x}{3}}{\frac{x}{3}} \frac{\sin \frac{x}{5}}{\frac{x}{5}} ...  \frac{\sin \frac{x}{2n+1}}{\frac{x}{2n+1}} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$ holds?

So it's a rather well known results to prove [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \,\mathrm dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-mathrm-dx-frac-pi)

and I use a computer program to validate that the general case does appear to hold, but not sure how to prove it..

Comment: It stops at $n=15$ or so if i remember correctly.

Comment: Yes that's correct. See this paper for a proof: https://carma.edu.au/resources/db90/pdfs/db90-119.00.pdf

Comment: I believe they use the n-dimensional convolution theorem for Fourier transforms, and the result that the Fourier transform of a sinc function is just a square wave

Answer (score 3):

These are [Borwein Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral) and the behavior of exactly equaling $\pi/2$ stops at $2n+1 = 15$.